# Counting in binary nybbles

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, binary

This challenge is to output to your terminal, window, canvas or screen the numbers zero to 10 inclusive. Each outputted number must be shown as a 4-bit wide nybble, so zero must show as `0000` and so on.

You may separate each number outputted with a space, comma or carriage return. Smallest solution wins but the numbers can be displayed in any order you like as long as there are no repeating numbers in your sequence.

Entries in low-level binary languages need not worry about the comma or white space separators if it is not possible to output with commas or white spaces (i.e., the standard output is limited to binary only, or your solution is for an early computer kit such as the [KIM-1](http://www.floodgap.com/retrobits/kim-1/) which has a limited digital display).

Comment: Yes, spaces, commas, a comma and then a space or a "\r\n" equivalent in your chosen language.

Comment: No sorry as that looks like 4 individual zero digits and not a 4-bit wide binary number.

Comment: Not that I'm really sure to write such an answer, but would it be OK to output some extra nibbles in addition to the 11 required ones?

Comment: They're nibbles, not nybbles.

Comment: Not according to the Commodore 64 Programmers reference guide

Comment: An example of how to do this in Commodore BASIC V2 is here: http://pastebin.com/2VTTMZgU using `DEF FN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SmileBASIC, 26 bytes

```
FOR I=0TO&HA?BIN$(I,4)NEXT
```

Answer (score 16):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 6 bytes

```
0:10YB
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=0%3A10YB&inputs=&version=19.7.4)

**Explanation**

```
0:10    % Create the array [0...10]
YB      % Convert this array to a binary string where each number is 
        % placed on a new row
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
T         # push 10
 4ã       # cartesian product repeat with 4
   R      # reverse list
    T>£   # take the first 11 elements of the list
      »   # join by newline and display
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x9icnhxUIjdocWHdv//DwA)

Comment: Wait... the Cartesian product of *the digits of a number?* That's just...

Answer (score 12):

### JavaScript, 46 bytes

```
for(i=15;i++<26;)alert(i.toString(2).slice(1))
```

Why use a padding function when you can simply add 16 to each number and slice off the first binary digit?

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
GôA,_¤Å
```

And here I was thinking Japt was doomed to be longer than every other golfing language...

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=R/RBLF+kxQ==&input=)

#### Explanation

```
GôA,_¤Å  // Implicit: A = 10, G = 16
GôA      // Create the inclusive range [G...G+A].
    _    // Map each item Z to Z
     ¤   //   .toString(2)
      Å  //   .slice(1).
         // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Normally commas can be removed in Japt, but this one is there because of a bug: `_` normally means `function(Z){Z`, but for some reason the compiler thinks `A_` means `function(A,Z){Z`.

Comment: Nice one. I got stuck at `Aô_¤`

Answer (score 8):

## Bash + GNU utils, 26

- 4 bytes saved thanks to @Dennis

```bash
seq -w 0 1010|sed /[2-9]/d
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@cWqigW65goGBoYGhQU5yaoqAfbaRrGauf8v8/AA).

Comment: `seq -w 0 1010` should work.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks - I don't remember using the `-w` option to `seq` before.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```bash
dc -e2o8927II^*8/p|fold -4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SrKCbapRvYWlk7ukZp2WhX1CTlp@ToqBr8v8/AA)

This is the same length as @DigitalTrauma/@Dennis's solution, but uses a completely different method.

Output is:

```bash
1010
0010
0110
0001
1001
0101
0100
0111
0011
1000
0000
```

(Any order is allowed.)

---

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 34 bytes

```bash
echo 0{0,1}{0,1}{0,1} 10{00,01,10}
```

[Try the pure Bash version online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvYFBtoGNYiyAUDIEiBjoGhjqGBrX//wMA)

Output is:

```bash
0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010
```

Answer (score 7):

## J, 6 bytes

```
#:i.11
```

Thanks to miles for cutting it down to 6 bytes!

Comment: `#:i.11` should work just as well

Comment: I'm not sure this is valid, as per [the answer to a now deleted comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61603/shaun-bebbers).

Comment: @Adám I can't view it. Could you please explain why it's not vaild?

Comment: Because it generates a n×4 Boolean array, which prints as digits with spaces in-between. But the comment seems to imply that spaces are not allowed inside the binary numbers.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3.6, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
i=11
while i:i-=1;print(f"{i:04b}")
```

-1 byte thanks to @JonathanAllan

#### Python 3.5 and earlier:

```
i=11
while i:i-=1;print("{:04b}".format(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59pa2jIVZ6RmZOqkGmVqWtraF1QlJlXoqFUbWVgklSrpJeWX5SbWKKRqan5/z8A)

Comment: `i=11` (new line) `while i:i-=1;print(f"{i:04b}")`, for 35.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
2Bṗ4ṫ6Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/k9HDndJOHO1ebRf7/DwA)**

(5 bytes if trailing lines of nybbles are allowed, `2Bṗ4Y`)

#### How?

Prints in descending order.

```
2Bṗ4ṫ6Y - Main link, no arguments
2B      - 2 converted to binary -> [1,0]
  ṗ4    - Cartesian 4th power -> [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,0], ..., [0,0,0,0]]
                            i.e.  16       , 15         ..., 0
    ṫ6  - tail from 6th item  -> [[1,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1], ..., [0,0,0,0]]
                            i.e.  10       , 9        , ..., 0
      Y - join with line feeds
        - implicit print
```

An alternative 7-byter is `2ṗ4Ịṫ6Y`, the `[1,0]` is replaced with `[1,2]` and `Ị` is the "is insignificant" monad (`abs(z)<=1`), converting `2`s to `0`s.

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
B{G+2b1>}%N*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@@9U7a5tlGRoV6vqp/X/PwA)

#### Explanation

The Cartesian power approach would have been my choice, but was already taken.

So this generates numbers from 0 to 10, and for each it adds 16 and converts to binary. Adding 16 ensures that the required leading zeros are produced, together with an extra leading one which is removed.

```
B             e# Push 11
 {      }%    e# Map over "11", implicitly converted to the array [0 1 ... 10]
  G+          e# Add 16. This makes sure there will be 5 binary digits: a leading 1
              e# which will have to be removed and the remaining, valid digits
    2b        e# Convert to array of binary digits
      1>      e# Remove first digit
          N*  e# Join by newlines. Implicitly converts arrays to strings
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 33 bytes

```
while($i<11)printf('%04b ',$i++);
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Intel 8080 machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080), [MITS Altair 8800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800), 10 bytes

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 76
```

Listing:

```
0000   00   NOP      
0001   00   NOP      
0002   00   NOP      
0003   00   NOP      
0004   00   NOP      
0005   00   NOP      
0006   00   NOP      
0007   00   NOP      
0008   00   NOP      
0009   00   NOP      
000A   76   HLT
```

Uses the CPU's program counter (PC, aka instruction pointer) to count from 0 to 10 then halt.  The output display is conveniently in nibble format already.

**Output:**

Output is displayed on [Blinkenlights](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blinkenlights-original.png#/media/File:Blinkenlights-original.png) A3-A0.

[image]

[Try it online!](https://s2js.com/altair/sim.html)

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB / Octave, 13 bytes

```
dec2bin(0:10)
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/sHy3Vm)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
2Ḷṗ4ḣ11Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/0cMe2hzunmzzcsdjQMPL/fwA)

#### How it works

```
2Ḷṗ4ḣ11Y  Main link.

2Ḷ        Unlength 2; yield [0, 1].
  ṗ4      Take the fourth Cartesian power.
    ḣ11   Head 11; discard all but the first eleven elements.
       Y  Join, separating by linefeeds.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10, 9</s>, 8 bytes

```
⁴r26BḊ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocUuRkZnTwx1dj5rWRP7/DwA)

I'm not that great at jelly, so I'd be open to any tips!

This uses [Emigna's first algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/110172/1)

---

*Thanks to Dennis for <s>shaving off two bytes</s> making me tie his own answer. :P*

Explanation:

```
      Ḋ€    # Return all but the first element of each item in the list:
⁴r26        #   [16, 17, 18, ... 26]
     B      #   Converted to binary
        Y   # And joined with newlines
```

Comment: `Ḋ€` saves a byte.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: `⁴r27` saves another one.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```python
n=16;exec"print bin(n)[3:];n+=1;"*11
```

*Thanks to @DJMcMayhem for golfing off 2 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59na2hmnVqRmqxUUJSZV6KQlJmnkacZbWwVa52nbWtoraRlaPj/PwA)

Comment: `for n in range(11):print bin(n+16)[3:]` also at 38 bytes.

Comment: `n=16;exec"print bin(n)[3:];n+=1;"*11` is two shorter

Comment: @DJMcMayhem It is indeed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

## RProgN, 15 Bytes

```
~16.aL1{2B26q}:
```

<s>This has been a *very* good modivation to add a `pad` function. The entirety of `]L4\-'0'\m\.`, more than half the code, is to pad.</s>

_Saved 6 bytes thanks to [@ETHProductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions), that's the pad function cut in half.

### Explained

```
~16.aL1{2B26q}:
~               # Zero Space Segment
 16.            # The literal number 16
    aL          # The length of the Alphabet
      1         # The literal number 1
       {     }: # For each number between 16 and 26 inclusive
        2B      # Convert to base 2
          26q   # Get the characters between 2 and 6 inclusive.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@19naKaX6GNYbeRkZFZYa/X/PwA)

Comment: `length of the Alphabet` Nice way to save a byte ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## BF, <s>121</s> 101 bytes

```
,....>,.<...+.>.<-..+.-.>.<..+..>.<-.+.-..>.<.+.-.+.>.<-.+..-.>.<.+...>.<.-...>.<+.-..+.>.<.-.+.-.!0
```

Requires a trailing newline. Makes use of `!` symbol (so, check the box that says `!`) with [this interpreter (try it online!)](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#LC4uLi4+LC48Li4uKy4+LjwtLi4rLi0uPi48Li4rLi4+LjwtLisuLS4uPi48LisuLS4rLj4uPC0uKy4uLS4+LjwuKy4uLj4uPC4tLi4uPi48Ky4tLi4rLj4uPC4tLisuLS4hMAo=).

Potentially 51 bytes if each operator was considered as 4 bits

Comment: You should specify (or additionally add a byte) for the `!` checkbox being enabled.

Comment: Whoops, I'm new to that and thought it encoded it in the URL. Will specify... wait, actually, I think it's already specified in the second sentence (?), will clarify that a bit

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```
%%%%
+`(^|\b)%
0$%'¶$%`1
11!`\d+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@8@lCgRc2gkacTUxSZqqXAYqquqHtqmoJhhyGRoqJsSkaP//DwA)

**Explanation**

```
%%%%
```

Replace the empty (non-existent) input with `%%%%`.

```
+`(^|\b)%
0$%'¶$%`1
```

On the first run of this stage, it will match `^%` and essentially replace the text `%%%%` with the two lines `0%%%` and `1%%%`. The stage will loop until the output stops changing. On the second run, it will match `\b%` (since digits count as word characters and `%` doesn't), and replace the groups by duplicating them and adding `0` to one copy and `1` to the other: `0%%%` becomes the lines `00%%` and `01%%` (and the same sort of thing for `1%%%`). Through this loop all 16 bitstrings will be produced, linefeed separated.

```
11!`\d+
```

The first 11 matches of `\d+` (a run of at least 1 digit) are retrieved. The matches are output in a linefeed-separated list.

Comment: I'm curious in understanding how this `0$%'¶$%`1` line works. What do `$%`, `\`1`, `'¶` represent?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Sorry I didn't explain the specifics, it's a bit convoluted :P. `$%\`` represents everything before the match on the same line, and `$%'` is everything after the match on the same line. `¶` is a literal linefeed. So basically the replacement matches the first `%` on a line and replaces it with `0` plus the rest of the line it was on, a newline, the beginning of the line it was on, and a `1`. Of course, the beginning and end of the line it was on are untouched by the replacement because they weren't part of the match.

Comment: So it's not putting a copy of the line after itself, but rather inserting the end of the line, a newline, and the beginning of the line in between the beginning and end of the line that remain intact.

Comment: Ah thanks, that was helpful  :) (I'm trying to learn Retina now)

Comment: In which case, I think you can use `G11\`` as the last line of the regex instead

Answer (score 2):

### C <s>170</s> 120 bytes

```
n,i,m,k[4]={0};f(){for(m=0;m<=10;m++){n=m;i=0;for(;n;i++){k[i]=n;n/=2;}for(i=4;i>0;i--)printf("%d",k[i-1]%2);puts("");}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void f()
{
    int n,i,m,k[4]={0};


   for(m=0;m<=10;m++)
   {
      n=m;
      i=0;

      for(;n;i++)
      {
         k[i]=n;
         n/=2;
      }  
      for(i=4;i>0;i--)
         printf("%d",k[i-1]%2);

      puts("");        
   }
}
```

Can definitely be shortened!?

@Ahemone Awesome idea, Thanks!

Should work now!
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#FYzBCoMwEAX/JSBkMaFRvL2uPyI5FIqwSLZi7Snk29PkMocZmKpOXHLHtkTOoSC9RC3l/XPZxAHpyVPjOFJWTpCmeoJCujs2iazQB88oPQgvkDVAvKfzEr13a4a3aX/xUxxmwvm7v9YYQim1/gE)

Comment: the first `for` loop in your golfed version should go to 4 rather than 3, but that doesn't matter because the loop can be eliminated entirely and the second for loop can start from 0. You can also just use `while(n)`, but compacting the `while` loop down into a `for` loop saves more again. `n/=2` will also save you a byte over the shift. You're also missing a terminating `}` on the golfed version causing an error on compilation.

Comment: @Ahemone Fixed the `}` and improved the code, 50 bytes shorter based on your idea.

Comment: [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##HctBCsIwEEbhuxSEDGmwLVkIv3OSkEUJqEOYUWpdlZ49Wrfv45VwL6U167WvKWboLOaEtttzcdDrOEI9vz7r23Ud0SY84CBjhcHOPFFN4n1m@3fhCAH9hvKYFxcvvqYQJJ8mwr639gU "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 25 bytes

```
11.times{|n|puts"%04b"%n}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>75</s> <s>68</s> 69 bytes

**Approach 1: <s>75</s> <s>73</s> <s>74</s> bytes**

```c
m;p(i){putchar(i?m&i?49:48:9);}r(){for(m=11;m--;p(4),p(2),p(1),p(0))p(8);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@rk6eTb52moVmdll@kkWtraGidq6trrQni5dnm6uTbmlrnAwXytGyNNAtKS5IzEos08u3z1CzsTSytTCysLDWta/9n5pUo5CZm5mmAGFU6CiBVWlqVmgrVXAoKCkDTreF07X8A)

---

**Approach 2: <s>68</s> 69 bytes**

```c
m,n,o;f(){for(m=11;m--;)for(n=m,o=5;o--;n*=2)putchar(o?n&8?49:48:9);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@rk6eTb52moVmdll@kkWtraGidq6trrQni5dnm6uTbmlrnAwXytGyNNAtKS5IzEos08u3z1CzsTSytTCysLDWta/9n5pUo5CZm5mmAGFU6CiBVWlqVmgrVXAoKCkDTreF07X8A)

Comment: Suggest `m,n;f(o)` instead of `m,n,o;f()`

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 96 bytes

---

**Golfed**

```cs
()=>{for(int i=0;i++<11;)System.Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToString(i,2).PadLeft(4,'0'));}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
() => {
    for( int i = 0; i++ < 1; )
        System.Console.WriteLine( System.Convert.ToString( i, 2 ).PadLeft( 4, '0' ) );
}
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
using System;

namespace Namespace {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            m();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void m() {
            for( Int32 i = 0; i++ < 11; )
                Console.WriteLine(
                    Convert.ToString( i, 2 ). // Converts the number to binary code
                    PadLeft( 4, '0' ) );      // Fills the number with the missing '0's
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.0** - `96 bytes` - Initial solution.

Comment: I like the release version you added - are you going to include RC versions as well? \o/

Comment: Going to be honest, don't know what **RC** means... [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78706/52814) is how I try to post my solutions in PPCG

Comment: RC means 'Release Candidate' - i.e., you'd send out a few versions with minor differences and await to see which is the most stable by your RC number. So if you had version A and version B, you could have v1.0-RCa and v1.0-RCb or something.

Comment: Oh, that. No. If I make another *release*, I increment the *Version Number* right away.

Answer (score 2):

### R - 23

We can use `intToBin` function from the **`R.utils`** package:

```
R.utils::intToBin(0:10)

[1] "0000" "0001" "0010" "0011" "0100" "0101" "0110" "0111" "1000" "1001" "1010"
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 68 bytes

```
f(){puts("0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010");}
```

Somehow, this is the shortest C answer so far…

EDIT: I was missing `1000` somehow. Well, it’s still winning.

Comment: Isn't this missing 8? (1000)

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore VIC-20/VC-20/C64 - <strike>95</strike> <strike>69</strike> <strike>68</strike> 67 tokenized BASIC bytes used (obfuscated and minimized)

```
0dEfnb(x)=sgn(xandb):fOi=0to10:b=8:fOj=0to3:?rI(stR(fnb(i)),1);:b=b/2:nE:?:nE
```

Copy and paste the above text into WinVice, for instance. Just about fits onto 80 characters on a Commodore 64.

Here's the non-obfuscated symbolic listing for illustrative purposes:

```
0 DEF FN B(X)=SGN(X AND B)
1 FOR I=0 TO 10
2  LET B=8
3  FOR J=0 TO 3
4   PRINT RIGHT$(STR$(FN B(I)),1);
5   LET B=B/2
6  NEXT J
7  PRINT
8 NEXT I
```

Of course this may be minimised and further obfuscated. Explanation:

The `DEF FN` command in line zero is a simple function which accepts one numeric parameter. This will give the algebraic sign the number passed to it as a parameter, in this case is `AND`ed with the value `B` (declared elsewhere, but becomes global once declared).

Line 1 starts the loop counter `I`

Line 2 sets the value of the 3rd BIT.

Line 3 starts loop counter `J` (we want bits 0 - 3 essentially).

Line 4 gets the `STR$` value (string value) of the function `FN B(I)`, this is then passed to the `RIGHT$` command as CBM BASIC auto-pads outputted numbers with a white space, so we get the last character in the string created by `STR$`.

Line 5 moves the BIT counter down one (like `x >> 1` in C I suppose).

Line 6 moves the `J` loop up one.

Line 7 prints a new line (line `echo PHP_EOL;` in PHP).

Line 8 moves the `I` loop up one.

I've 'nested' the listing in the example to better show the loop and loop order.

[image: C64 counting in nybbles]

Comment: Thanks, I've done this in the obfuscated version above (although not the `NEXT J` one) - I'll give it a go for that as well, saving another BASIC byte!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 44 bytes

```
for x in range(11):print bin(x)[2:].zfill(4)
```

This uses the `zfill` function which works like `rjust` except it always padds with `0` so you don't waste bytes on an argument.

Comment: Wait what, this whole time I've been wasting bytes making my own padding function? (`lambda k,l:' '*(len(k)-l)+k`) Wow... +1 just because of this :D

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 8 bytes

```
TFw0+b2t
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=TFw0%2Bb2t)

```
TFw0+b2t - for i in range(10):
  w0+    -    i+16
     b2  -   bin(^)
       t -  ^[:-1]
```

Also 8 bytes:

```
TF 4@b2t
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=TF+4%40b2t)

```
   4@    - set_bit(4, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 38 bytes

```
11.times{|i|puts i.to_s(2).rjust 4,?0}
```

Comment: -1 byte by getting rid of the parentheses: `11.times{|i|puts i.to_s(2).rjust 4,?0}`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
<5^_`T4
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3C5%5E_%60T4&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 30 bytes

```
11:>[2 baserep'0'4 pad out]map
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#@29oaGUXbaSQlFicWpRaoG6gbqJQkJiikF9aEpubWPD/PwA)

`11:>` is a range from `0` to `10`. The rest is rather self-explanatory.

Other solutions that I've found:

```
11:>[bits 4 dpad''join out]map
11:>[bits 4 dpad$tostrmap]map out
11~>15+[bits behead''join out]map
16 26|>[bits behead''join out]map
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BF](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 134 bytes

I'm sure this can be shortened--it's pretty much my first BF golf.

```
++++++++++[>+>+>+++++>>>+++++>>>+++++>>>+++++[<<<]>>>-]>>+>[-->>+>]<<<[<<<]>>[>[>>-[<<+.->]<[>]>-[<<.>]<[>]>++>]<-[<<<-]++<<[<<<]>.>-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#bUzbDcBACBqI4ASGRYz7j2GxufbrIBHBx@BHCcuFdNfKzLahC1TkSjs8gzJFGwSdl/p1cXrs8gbJBr6r8LuZBw) Assumes a tape infinite in both directions, like the interpreter at TIO uses. An interpreter where `<` at the left end of the tape is a no-op would save three bytes.

#### Explanation

More than half of the code (the first 77 bytes, to be precise) is spent initializing the tape. The steps go like this:

```
++++++++++
10|

[>+>+>+++++>>>+++++>>>+++++>>>+++++[<<<]>>>-]
 0|10|10|50| 0| 0|50| 0| 0|50| 0| 0|50|

>>+>[-->>+>]<<<[<<<]>>
 0|10|11|48| 0| 1|48| 0| 1|48| 0| 1|48| 0| 1|
```

The cells initialized to `1` store the bits of our number plus 1: `1` represents a zero bit and `2` represents a one bit.

The initialization phase ended with the pointer on the `11`. Now we use this cell to run 11 iterations of our loop:

```
[>          Move to the first 48
 [>>-       While we're still on a 48, move 2 cells over and decrement
  [         The cell's value now equals the bit it represents; if it's not 0:
   <<+.-    Move to the 48, increment, output, and decrement again
   >        Move to the next cell, which holds a 0
  ]         Leave the loop
  <[>]>     Pointer shenanigans to get back on the cell representing the bit
  -         Decrement again: cell is 255 for a zero bit, 0 for a one bit
  [         If cell is not 0:
   <<.>     Move to the 48, output, and move to the 0 cell
  ]
  <[>]>++   Get back on the bit's cell; increment back to original value
  >         Move to the next 48
 ]          Loop exits once we've output all four bits
            Now we increment the binary number: a one bit turns into a zero bit and
            carries; a zero bit turns into a one bit and doesn't carry
 <-         Move back to the rightmost bit cell and decrement
 [          If it is not 0, it must represent a one
  <<<-      Leave it decremented, go to the next bit cell and decrement it too
 ]          Loop exits on a bit cell that represented a zero
 ++         Increment it twice (to represent a one)
 <<[<<<]    Move back to first cell on tape
 >.         Move to 10 cell and output (newline)
 >-         Move to loop counter cell and decrement
]
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 110? bytes

```
n,i,m,k[4]={0};f(){for(m=-1;(n=++m)<11;i=0){for(;n;n>>=1)k[i++]=n;for(i=4;i--;)printf("%d",k[i]&1);puts("");}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int f() {
    int n,i,m,k[4]={0};
    for(m=-1;(n=++m)<11;i=0) {
        for(;n;n>>=1)
            k[i++]=n;
        for(i=4;i--;)
            printf("%d",k[i]&1);
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, <del>41</del> <del>39</del> <del>34</del> 32

*2+5=7 bytes removed thanks to PrzemysławP.*

I am using [the `FORMAT` function](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node200.html) function, for printing a number as binary with padding and separators, called with the magic number 8800979740570 (a.k.a. 8012345679A in base 16):

```
CL-USER> (format t"~,,,4:b"8800979740570)
1000,0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1001,1010
```

I used to do the same with *123456789A*, but as noted by *PrzemysławP*, the order does not matter and we can save some bytes. This is because with the original order, the leading zeros would be done as padding and would not be separated into groups of 4 digits; here, by starting with *1000*, we don't need any padding. In addition to that, I also removed the *mincol* argument (53) because I don't need to specify the size of the number anymore.

### Formatted output of integers

The documentation for format (see above) is detailed for `~D` (decimal base) but the same applies to other ones (hex `~X`, binary `~B`, octal `~O`, custom `~R`). Note that for floats there are other arguments.

The most general format is `~mincol,padchar,commachar,commaintervalD`, but note that the two last arguments, *commachar* and *commainterval* are only meaningful if `D` has a colon-modifier `:D`, which by default separate digits by groups of 3 (*commainterval* is a custom value, instead of 3), inserting the *commachar* character between such groups, by default a comma.

The *mincol* argument is one that is found in other format directives and specifies the horizontal space allocated for the thing being printed. When the actual size required is smaller, a padding might be applied (left or right, or both for some directives). The padding fills the remaining space with *padchar*, a character. When the actual size is bigger, the layout might not be pretty but the object is printed fully.

More precisely (from the above link):

> `~D` Decimal. An arg, which should be an integer, is printed in decimal
>   radix. `~D` will never put a decimal point after the number. `~mincolD`
>   uses a column width of *mincol*; spaces are inserted on the left if the
>   number requires fewer than *mincol* columns for its digits and sign. If
>   the number doesn't fit in *mincol* columns, additional columns are used
>   as needed.
>
> `~mincol,padcharD` uses *padchar* as the pad character instead of space.
>
> The @ modifier causes the number's sign to be printed always; the
>   default is to print it only if the number is negative.
>
> The : modifier
>   causes commas to be printed between groups of three digits
>
> the third
>   prefix parameter may be used to change the character used as the
>   comma. Thus the most general form of ~D is ~mincol,padchar,commacharD.
>
> *X3J13 voted in March 1988 (FORMAT-COMMA-INTERVAL)* to
>   add a fourth parameter, the commainterval. This must be an integer; if
>   it is not provided, it defaults to 3. This parameter controls the
>   number of digits in each group separated by the commachar.
>
> By extension, each of the ~B, ~O, and ~X directives accepts a
>   commainterval as a fourth parameter, and the ~R directive accepts a
>   commainterval as its fifth parameter.

#### Padding and separators

Note that the padding characters are not grouped, as explained above. For example, the zeros in front of the numbers are not separated:

```
 CL-USER> (format t "~10,'0:d" 12345)
 000012,345
```

... there is no easy way to combine format parameters to output:

```
 000,012,345
```

... that's why I first added the zeros and a comma explicitly in the answer. This is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Nice solution! You can save 2 bytes with: `(format t"0000,~49,'0,,4:b"78187493530)` - instead of space use comma as separator

Comment: Could you explain how does this directive work? ~mincol,padchar, and what later? I know `4` is length of group and `:b` for binary system. Are there more arguments later? Does it work similiar to ~R?

Comment: @PrzemysławP I added some explanations. It is the same for ~R, but with five parameters (the first one is the radix, i.e. the base).

Comment: `(format t"~53,,,4:b"8800979740570)` saves additional 5 bytes - uses fact that any order is allowed.

Comment: @PrzemysławP That's clever, I didn't pay attention to the order. Btw, I also  removed "53" because in fact the size is not necessary. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## SAS, 39 bytes

Not very creative...

```
data t;do i=0 to 10;put i binary4.;end;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 44 bytes

`(0..10).each{|e|puts (16+e).to_s(2)[-4..-1]}`

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 41 bytes

```
(dotimes(i 11)(format t"~5,,,'0<~B ~>"i))
```

Different method than other CL submission.

Answer (score 1):

## ***Perl 6, <s>25</s> 22 bytes***

```
printf "%04b "x 11,^11
```

Fairly similar to the ruby answer.
EDIT: Saved 3 bytes by removing parantheses.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 195 bytes

```
interface C{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;i++<11;)System.out.println(((java.util.function.Function<String,String>)x->("0000"+x).substring(x.length())).apply(Integer.toString(i-1,2)));}}
```

I am never golfing in Java again...

-2 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 32 bytes

```
do i=0 to 10
  say x2b(d2x(i))
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
Aò¤ù'0
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=QfKk+Scw&input=)

```
Aò¤ù'0
A          :10
 ò         :Range [0,A]
  ¤        :Convert each to binary
   ù       :left pad each to length of longest
    '0     :  With "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 92 bytes

```hs
0#_="";b#n=(if even$n`div`b then"0"else"1")++(div b 2#n)
main=putStr.unwords.map(8#)$[0..10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoQgFADQfaeQbwslEGsVhKdoOQyl9CPJfpJWx3fmLd9m044hlKL5ZAAGx8kIvzJ8kGqaF//MjuUNCTRgSAgtyKYR/2eOdZxkdVhPJt55zJe66T2vJanDRtFzWX@0Uq3@lvID)

Answer (score 1):

Java 8, 77 bytes

```
()->{for(int i=43;i>=0;i--)System.out.print(((i/4>>i%4)&1)+(i%4==0?" ":""));}
```

For each number, print one bit at a time by bit shifting then masking with &1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 22 bytes

```perl
printf'%04b 'x11,0..10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1d1cAkSUG9wtBQx0BPz9Dg/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```rust
||for i in 0..11{print!("{:04b} ",i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUM2loJCTWqKQpmD7v6YmLb9IIVMhM0/BQE/P0LC6oCgzr0RRQ6naysAkqVZBSSdTs/a/NVBHmoamNVftfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 57 bytes

```forth
: f 11. do 4. do j 3 i - rshift 2 mod 1 .r loop cr loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcXRCYAwDEDBVd4CLUT90nEssRUlErt/RPHnTs17TZu@RcwoIpliTJ87I42E37VpZ@C0gpCdw@xi/V9C4wE)

#### Explanation

- Loop from 0 to 10 (inclusive)

  - For each iteration:
  - Loop from 0 to 3, print the character at that index (with no space)
  - Print a newline

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                 \ start a new word definition
  11.               \ place 11 and 0 on stack
  do                \ loop from 0 to 10
    4.              \ place 4 and 0 on the stack
    do              \ loop from 0 to 3
      j             \ place outer loop index (current number) on stack
      3 i -         \ get the position of the digit we care about
      rshift 2 mod  \ get the value at that position
      1 .r          \ print the binary digit with no space appended
    loop            \ end the inner loop
    cr              \ print a newline
  loop              \ end the outer loop
;                   \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Ar☻+mÅà╞n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@x6NGM3dq5h1sPL3g0dV7e//8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ar        # Push a list in the range [0,11): [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  ☻+      # Add 16 to each: [16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
    m     # Map each value to,
     Å    # using the following two commands:
      à   #  Convert the value to a binary string
       ╞  #  And remove the first digit
    n     # After the map: join the list by newlines
          # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

The first four bytes could alternatively be `A╒E+`:

```python
A╒        # Push a list in the range [1,11]: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
  E+      # Add 15 to each: [16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16, IBM PC DOS, 28 bytes

Binary (build `NIB.COM` with `xxd -r`):

```
00000000: b30a 53b1 04d2 e3b8 000e d0d3 1430 cd10  ..S..........0..
00000010: e2f5 b820 0ecd 105b 4b79 e7c3            ... ...[Ky..
```

Unassembled listing:

```
B3 0A       MOV  BL, 10         ; set initial counter 
        NIB_LOOP: 
53          PUSH BX             ; save counter in BX 
B1 04       MOV  CL, 4          ; shift / loop 4 times 
D2 E3       SHL  BL, CL         ; shift left one nibble/nybble 
        BIT_LOOP:    
B8 0E00     MOV  AX, 0E00H      ; BIOS write to console / zero AL
D0 D3       RCL  BL, 1          ; rotate left one bit, MSB into carry 
14 30       ADC  AL, '0'        ; add carry bit to '0' ASCII char 
CD 10       INT  10H            ; write to console 
E2 F5       LOOP BIT_LOOP       ; keep looping to next bit 
B8 0E20     MOV  AX, 0E20H      ; BIOS write to console / space 
CD 10       INT  10H            ; write to console 
5B          POP  BX             ; restore counter 
4B          DEC  BX             ; is >= 0? 
79 E7       JNS  NIB_LOOP       ; if so, keep looping 
C3          RET                 ; exit to DOS
```

#### Output

[image]

Standalone PC DOS executable .COM program.  Output is to console, descending separated by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>107</del> 106 bytes

```
for(i in[0,1])for(j in[0,1])for(k in[0,1])[0,1].each{|l|
System.printAll([i,j,k,l])
if(i==1&&k==1)Fn.x()
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/Py2/SCNTITMv2kDHMFYTxMtC4WXDeWBSLzUxOaO6JqeGK7iyuCQ1V6@gKDOvxDEnRyM6UydLJ1snJ1aTKzNNI9PW1lBNLRtIarrl6VVoaHLV/v8PAA)

### Explanation

```
for(i in[0,1])for(j in[0,1])for(k in[0,1])[0,1].each{|l| // Define all those binary digits
System.printAll([i,j,k,l])                                // Print all the binary digits
if(i==1&&k==1)                                            // If the number has reached 10,
              Fn.x()                                      // Execute an undefined command in the Fn class
                                                          // That breaks out of all of the 4 for loops and stops the program
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `Rj`, 38 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.75 bytes

```
₀ƛΠṅ∷
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9UmoiLCIiLCLigoDGm86g4bmF4oi3IiwiIiwiIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
10101010010101010011110101110100101100
```

VYXAL FOREVER RAHHHHH

```
₀ƛΠṅ∷­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
₀      # ‎⁡push 10
 ƛ     # ‎⁢map over the range [0,10] (R flag)
  Π    # ‎⁣binary string
   ṅ   # ‎⁤padded to length 8
    ∷  # ‎⁢⁡second half
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).