# Negative Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, fibonacci

You probably all know the fibonacci sequence:

```
fibonacci(n)=fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)
fibonacci(0)=0
fibonacci(1)=1
```

Your task is as simple as it could be:

- Given integer `N` compute `fibonacci(n)`

but here is the twist:

- Also do negative `N`

Wait. What?

```
fibonacci(1)=fibonacci(0)+fibonacci(-1)
```

so

```
fibonacci(-1)=1
```

and

```
fibonacci(-2)=fibonacci(0)-fibonacci(1)=-1
```

and so on...

- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest programm in bytes win.
- You may submit a function or a full programm
- N is in [-100,100]

Testcase(s) in CSV:

```
-9;-8;-7;-6;-5;-4;-3;-2;-1;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
34;-21;13;-8;5;-3;2;-1;1;0;1;1;2;3;5;8;13;21
```

Hint:

> n<0 and n&1==0:
>
> ```
> fibonacci(n)=fibonacci(abs(n))*-1
> ```

Comment: No. Mine wants you to support negative numbers too.

Comment: I think this is not a dupe. Of the answers on the first page of the existing Fibonacci challenge, only 1 can handle negatives, and all the rest would need to be significantly changed to go backwards too.

Comment: Added some. Feel free to add more. @Flip

Comment: Read [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8101/60919) about formatting test cases: try to avoid fancy tables

Comment: and by CSV you mean SSV (semicolon separated values)?

Comment: @NH. "European CSV" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example

Answer (score 23):

## Mathematica, 9 bytes

```
Fibonacci
```

Yes, this built-in function supports negative numbers.

Comment: This is almost word-for-word the answer I was coming to post :D

Answer (score 18):

## Octave, 20 bytes

```
 @(n)([1,1;1,0]^n)(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaepEW2oY2htqGMQGwfkGGn@T8wr1jDQ/A8A)

#### Explanation

This makes use of the fact that the fibonacci sequence `f(n)` can be written as (this should be a matrix vector notation):

Recursively:

```
[f(n+1)]  = [1  1] * [f(n)  ]
[f(n)  ]    [1  0]   [f(n-1)]
```

Explicitly:

```
[f(n+1)]  = [1  1] ^n * [1]
[f(n)  ]    [1  0]      [0]
```

This means that the top right entry of this matrix to the power of `n` is the value `f(n)` we're looking for. Obviously we can also invert this matrix as it has full rank, and the relationship still describes the same recurrence relation. That means it also works for negative inputs.

Comment: (How) Does this also work for negative input?

Comment: yes, explanation coming...

Comment: is `ans(-6)` meant to be positive?

Comment: @FlipTack Sorry, it might have been because of the index shift. I used 1-based, while the question used 0-based, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 13):

## Maxima, 3 bytes

```
 fib
```

supports positive and negative numbers.

Try it (paste) on [CESGA - Maxima on line](http://maxima.cesga.es/)

Comment: Can you add a link to the language?

Comment: Of course added a link to an online calculator!

Comment: Also works on WolframAlpha

Answer (score 12):

### Python, 43 bytes

```python
g=5**.5/2+.5
lambda n:(g**n-(1-g)**n)/5**.5
```

A direct formula with the golden ratio `g`. With `f` the above function:

```python
for n in range(-10,11):print f(n) 

-55.0
34.0
-21.0
13.0
-8.0
5.0
-3.0
2.0
-1.0
1.0
0.0
1.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
5.0
8.0
13.0
21.0
34.0
55.0
```

Same length alt, only aliasing the square root of 5:

```python
a=5**.5
lambda n:((a+1)**n-(1-a)**n)/a/2**n
```

I didn't see a way to make a recursive function that could compete with these. A mildly-golfed attempt for 57 bytes:

```python
f=lambda n:n<0and(-1)**n*f(-n)or n>1and f(n-1)+f(n-2)or n
```

For comparison, an iterative method (60 bytes in Python 2):

```python
n=input()
a,b=0,1;exec"a,b=b,a+b;"*n+"a,b=b-a,a;"*-n
print a
```

Or, for 58 bytes:

```python
n=input()
a,b=0,1;exec"a,b=b,a+cmp(n,0)*b;"*abs(n)
print a
```

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

```js
f=n=>n<2?n<0?f(n+2)-f(n+1):n:f(n-2)+f(n-1)
```

#### Test

```js
f=n=>n<2?n<0?f(n+2)-f(n+1):n:f(n-2)+f(n-1)

for(i = -9; i < 9; i++) {
  console.log(i, f(i))
}
```

Comment: I really like your function. I had a suggestion here, but I overlooked a -, so it wouldn't work...

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7) 37 bytes

Uses [Binet's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html).

```
n=>((1+(a=5**.5))**n-(1-a)**n)/a/2**n
```

This outputs the `n`<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number +- `0.0000000000000005`.

Comment: `**` requires ES7.

Comment: Oh, thought it was part of ES6, but you're right. Changed it. I also used another version of Binet's Formula for a 1B save.

Comment: Now that I think about it, just using `1-p` instead of `-1/p` should have worked for the same saving.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

<s>I'm happy about the `[3,2]`, which surely could be golfed, if anyone knows a way please let me know=) (It would also work with `[1,3]`.)</s> Thanks @LuisMendo for -2 bytes=)

```
IHhBiY^2)
```

This is using the same approach as the [Octave annswer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105183/fibonacci-1fibonacci0-fibonacci1/105184#105184). But to generate the matrix

```
[1,1]
[1,0]
```

we just conver the number `3` and `2` from decimal to binary (i.e. `11` and `10`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@/pkeGUGRlnpPn/v64JAA)

Answer (score 4):

## Jolf, 2 bytes

```
mL
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=bUw)

The fibonacci builtin, implemented using the `phi` formula.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token |
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at p (math.min.js:27)
    at Object (math.min.js:27)
    at typed (eval at p (math.min.js:27), <anonymous>:36:14)
    at Object.n [as factory] (math.min.js:45)
    at t (math.min.js:27)
    at f (math.min.js:27)
    at Object.get [as median] (math.min.js:27)
    at clone (rawgit.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/master/src/jolf.js:902)
    at rawgit.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/master/src/jolf.js:2128 (Latest Google Chrome, version 55.0.2883.87m)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel This should only work on firefox

Comment: I had no idea, it isn't anywhere

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 51 bytes

```
s=0:scanl(+)1s;f z|even z,z<0= -f(-z);f z=s!!abs z
```

Comment: Multiple tests within a guard can be combined with `,` instead of `&&`: `even z,z<0`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 88 bytes

```
#N::((if(< N 2)((if(< N 0)((-(f(+ N 2))(f(+ N 1))))((+ N))))((+(f(- N 2))(f(- N 1))))))
```

My look at all those [parentheses](https://xkcd.com/297/).

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/lithp-webide/?code=KAogICAgKGRlZiBmICNOOjooCiAgICAgICAgKGlmICg8IE4gMikgKAogICAgICAgICAgICAoaWYgKDwgTiAwKSAoCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAoLSAoZiAoKyBOIDIpKSAoZiAoKyBOIDEpKSkKICAgICAgICAgICAgKSAoCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAoKyBOKQogICAgICAgICAgICApKQogICAgICAgICkgKAogICAgICAgICAgICAoKyAoZiAoLSBOIDIpKSAoZiAoLSBOIDEpKSkKICAgICAgICApKQogICAgKSkKICAgIChpbXBvcnQgbGlzdHMpCiAgICAoZWFjaCAoc2VxICgtIDkpIDgpICNJIDo6ICgocHJpbnQgIkZvciAiIEkgIjogIiAoZiBJKSkpKQop)

Not very small really. There's currently a parsing bug that requires one to use `(get N)` or `(+ N)` instead of simply `N`. I chose the smaller one. However I don't think there's anything that can be done further to golf this.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 112 Bytes

```
function f($n){$o=('-','+')[$n-lt0];&(({$a,$b=(2,1|%{f("$n$o$_"|iex)});"$a- $o$b"|iex},{$n*$n})[$n-in(-1..1)])}
```

**Demo Call:**

```
-9..9 | %{"{0,2}`t=> {1,3}" -f $_,(f($_))}
```

**Output of Demo:**

```
-9  =>  34
-8  => -21
-7  =>  13
-6  =>  -8
-5  =>   5
-4  =>  -3
-3  =>   2
-2  =>  -1
-1  =>   1
 0  =>   0
 1  =>   1
 2  =>   1
 3  =>   2
 4  =>   3
 5  =>   5
 6  =>   8
 7  =>  13
 8  =>  21
 9  =>  34
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
ÆḞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Md8/7rWhZZKlgfbld51LRGwf0/AA)

Boring builtin answer, Jelly’s Fibonacci builtin handles negative inputs just fine