# Complex Fibonacci numbers

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci, complex-numbers

The [Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) is a closed form expression for the \$n\$'th [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number):

$$F_n = \frac {\phi^n - (1-\phi)^n} {\sqrt 5}$$

where \$\phi = \frac {1 + \sqrt 5} 2\$ is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). This formula works even when \$n\$ is [negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Negafibonacci) or rational, and so can be a basis to calculating "complex Fibonacci numbers".

For example, by setting \$n = \frac 1 2\$, we can calculate \$F_\frac 1 2\$ as:

$$F_\frac 1 2 = \frac 1 {\sqrt 5} \left( \sqrt \frac {1+\sqrt 5} 2 - \sqrt \frac {1-\sqrt 5} 2 \right) \\
\approx 0.56886-0.35158i$$

You are to take a floating point, \$-10 \le n \le 10\$, with up to 3 decimals after the point, and output \$F_n\$, accurate to at least 5 decimal places. You may either round or truncate, so long as it is consistent. You may also choose to input as a rational number if you wish, or as a `(numerator, denominator)` pair. You may also choose whether integers should be suffixed with `.0` or not, so long as it is consistent across all 21 integer inputs.

As the output will be a complex number in all but 21 cases, you may output in any reasonable format for such a type, including outputting as a `(real, imag)` pair. For the integer inputs, the imaginary part will be \$0\$. You may choose whether to output the imaginary part in this case (and returning an integer  or float is perfectly fine).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

These all round their output, rather than truncate.

```
  n       Re(Fn)     Im(Fn)
-10      -55         0
  1        1         0
 -7       13         0
  3        2         0
  0.5      0.56886  -0.35158
  5.3      5.75045   0.02824
  7.5     16.51666   0.01211
 -1.5      0.21729  -0.92044
 -9.06    34.37587  -6.55646
  9.09    35.50413   0.00157
 -2.54     0.32202   1.50628
  5.991    7.96522   0.00071
 -6.033   -8.08507   0.84377
  8.472   26.36619  -0.00756
```

And a script to output [all possible outputs](https://tio.run/##TY27DsIwDEXn5ivuhg0tT4FEJVZG/iFAC5EaJ4QgUSG@vaSFAQ@27tGx7dt4dbLqujo4i3trfQtjvQsR91uIOQ5K@avBDrTAZGC0ZsYMS6XqhBttj2cNKUG9Nx5DUPRygZR5AL3@20xLLiTFCIKWS0XFYp4qxzC4VJlgthuSyvaSHpyc9U31pAPVJMysMh@MRBq9ys0br3L7baNpOmx1JMkR3EPOtJdpqHSTY81/yFh9@SLmrvsA) in the same format (gets cut off on TIO due to the length).

Comment: Brownie points for beating my 11 byte Jelly answer

Comment: No one's done a language without complex number or vector support... For example, is this even possible in Javascript?

Comment: Relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghxQA3vvhsk

Comment: @Ausername Besides the fact this has been answered in JS already, it's pretty obvious this is possible in JS given it's plainly turing-complete

Comment: $$F(n) = \frac{\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5} 2\right)^n - \left( \frac {1-\sqrt 5} 2 \right)^n}{\sqrt5}$$

Comment: Complex roots are multi-valued in general, so how do you define exactly $(1-\phi)^{p/q}$? Is any of the $q$ possible results valid?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The output should be the principal root

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/105183/58563) (as pointed out by tsh [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223073/58563)).

Comment: @Ausername: Yes, it's very possible to solve without builtin complex number support.  Those languages have to implement it somehow, e.g. complex multiply of `c1a + i * c1b` times c2a/b is `real = ((c1a * c2a) - (c1b * c2b))`  `imag = ((c1b * c2a) + (c1a * c2b))`.  A power function producing a complex result for negative bases is even more of a chore to implement manually, so I'm not surprised few people have. (Although apparently not as bad as I thought if you can use sin and cos as building blocks; implementing *those* in terms of basic operations like + - / * and lookup tables is not simple)

Answer (score 10):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
(h=2/--√5;h^#-(1-h)^#)√.2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7XyPD1khfV/dRxyxT64w4ZV0NQ90MzThlTaCAnpHa/8DSzNQSh4CizLySaGVduzQH5Vi1uuDkxLy6ai5dQwMdLgUFQyChaw5iGYMIAz1TEGWqB@aZg3m6hhDKUs/ADCQKpC1BfCM9UxOIYktLsDFmegbGYH0WeibmRly1/wE)

Uses \$\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt 5-1}\$. Mathematica's pre-increment/decrement operators still return the desired value when used on (non-variable) non-atoms.

The built-in [`Fibonacci`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fibonacci.html) is a continuous real function, the real part of the Binet formula: \$F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\cos(\pi n)\phi^{-n}}{\sqrt 5}\$.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>60</s> <s>57</s> 41 bytes

<s>Just the straightforward golfed implementation. Stole the `sqrt()` = `^.5` trick from Level River St.</s>

att and Dominic van Essen golfed off several bytes, thank you. My algebra is rusty! This version takes arguments in complex number notation.

```r
function(x,g=.5+5^.5/2)(g^x-(1-g)^x)/5^.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZCxbsMwDET3fAWBLjZSMSQlUtKQX/HQAjGypEDRAv57V5KVxk21Sfd0d@Tnerm@ndfL9@396/pxG5bX@Yx61An1JOMwT4sb2M3jtIyn@ljxARzTka4AMMILOFXohw5NBt7UJgPDk@ziTmb/LIPf/5Z/MpV@FWhyuVhKBuAIvbKmDin6B6QYlUJtSUiSJHQo7pzYUNnMNoiFuZflv3HCUXKLy0KhO7mMZJWqkA/oo6ZYoOKpFqzHFSj/QoqlUhu@xBFr7E6CGu5QkbwI1RWUFmTymC7nuuMGRcymIt2J4r24IXnfIZeQklJsUAo@9jhIGKJ0SAy9GW/TFSO1w/oD)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYw9CsMwDEb3nkQikWI7UVwPuYqXgCFLCnULhpKzu5Xd5T19@nvWtNX0PvfX8TihjHljGSSyTA4/kGMhsJQHc2AsOOngqgnIGrwlsAryyllhWFTCLfmeyP4d2Kxa/Bxaw7EsfT@E/mplM7fbOy/eYf0C) (Also, you didn't update the TIO link)

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZCxbsMwDET3fAWBLjZSMSQlUtKQX/HQAgm8pEDRAPl7V5bpNmg1EbqnO54@l8v8dl4u99v71/xxGx6v1zPqUSfUkxxpHofr9AgDh@s4PcbTer@@GCAwAcAILxBUwQ8dugYMrm3TsxbyrnH8q0H8eSf/NEJ1rU1WigEEwqisxQnF6IRiVkrrWoQkRZITefdgQ2Uz2wgWZt@On1KEs9SeUoWSe4SKZJ2ICWPW0vqE5qaWzFMaUTdCsa3Re7YUYs3uIahpT4kitLZtyWTy26VW7kTGairiHpT3TQ0pxv7/Bako5U6UFLOnQMGUZSXEMJrx1qVZqB2W5Rs)...

Comment: ...or [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZCxbsMwDET3fAWBLjZSMSQlUtKQX/HQAjGypEDRAv57V5KVxk21Sfd0d@Tnerm@ndfL9@396/pxG5bX@Yx61An1JOMwT4sb2M3jtIyn@ljxARzTka4AMMILOFXohw5NBt7UJgPDk@ziTmb/LIPf/5Z/MpV@FWhyuVhKBuAIvbKmDin6B6QYlUJtSUiSJHQo7pzYUNnMNoiFuZflv3HCUXKLy0KhO7mMZJWqkA/oo6ZYoOKpFqzHFSj/QoqlUhu@xBFr7E6CGu5QkbwI1RWUFmTymC7nuuMGRcymIt2J4r24IXnfIZeQklJsUAo@9jhIGKJ0SAy9GW/TFSO1w/oD) with input using complex number notation.

Answer (score 7):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 20 bytes

```matlab
@(n)([1 1;1 0]^n)(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7PCoAgDMDhe0@xox4cW2YmEfQe/YGIPNYlen0TLPX07ccYXvu9PUfwwxxGcUoxMXDPQMsah1oGLxQTxCcrLwA4U9lSdSGh@WlQ/7S5Ki50SO23EOm@WqNp8gXnONUWSetUO2xs/NkL)

You know, this classical Fibonacci number formula still works here...

$$
F_x=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^x\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

Aha, after I posted this answer. I try some searching about it. And I finally found out [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr)'s [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105184/44718) to [Negative Fibonacci Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105183) question. It just using the same codes. Also there are many other answers may simply fit this questions' requirement. I'm not sure if this is a duplicate here, but... They does solve this question with short codes...

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda x,p=.5+5**.5/2:(p**x-(1-p)**x)/5**.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp8BWz1TbVEtLz1TfyEqjQEurQlfDULdAE8jQ1AeL/y8oyswr0UjT0DU00NTkgvEMkdi65kgcY2RF@kZIPFNjfVQjTFGkdY1RuSZA9aZA9f8B)

-6 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing (old version)
-6 bytes thanks to Noodle9 (old version)

-a lot of bytes after realizing i don't need sympy thanks to Noodle9
-1 byte thanks to dingledooper

Comment: You use `5**.5` twice. I don't know Python but can you set up a constant for this? I managed to save some bytes doing this in Ruby

Comment: @LevelRiverSt defining `a` as `5**.5` and using `a` twice is the same length as using `5**.5` twice since i need the newline after the definition, and so i end up taking +2 bytes because i need to define `a` first and therefore have to move `f=` into the body. i'll think about golfing opportunities relating to this though. thanks!

Comment: Python has complex number support? What?

Comment: What about `.5+5**.5/2` instead of `(1+5**.5)/2`?

Comment: @Ausername: Sure. Look into the [`complex` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex), [imaginary number literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals), and [the standard `cmath` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html).

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
17Lt_Qwhi^d5X^/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39DcpyQ@sDwjMy7FNCJO//9/Cz0TcyMA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N/Q3KckPrA8IzMuxTQiTv@/S8h/XUMDLkMuXXMuYy4DPVMuUz1jLnMgrWsIIiz1DMy4gIQll66RnqkJUNbSEqjYTM/A2JjLQs/E3EgBAA).

#### Explanation

```
17L    % Push ϕ (predefined literal)
t_Q    % Duplicate, negate, add 1: gives 1-ϕ
wh     % Swap, concatenate horizontally: gives [1-ϕ, ϕ]
i^     % Input n, element-wise power: gives [(1-ϕ)^n, ϕ^n]
d      % Consecutive difference(s): gives ϕ^n - (1-ϕ)^n
5X^    % Push 5, square root
/      % Divide: gives (ϕ^n - (1-ϕ)^n) / sqrt(5)
       % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
⭆¹ΣＥ∕Ｘ⊘⊕⟦₂⁵±₂⁵⟧Ｎ₂⁵⎇μ⁻⁰λλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUy7DsIwDPyVjI4UUBk6sTLQoVVF2RCDaa0SKY/WJEV8fUjGnnS6h60b38ijR5NSz9oFGEKWucUFTkoM0UKxF73piaD3X2K4otlogsaNTJZcyP4xrBGZbt4HqKUSHc0YCHatfMp8adwSQxftKw@VvH9R4k7skH9glWi1ix@olDCysOCcUnWs02Ezfw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
          ⁵                 Literal `5`
         ₂                  Square root
             ⁵              Literal `5`
            ₂               Square root
           ±               Negated
        ⟦     ⟧             Make into list
       ⊕                    Vectorised increment
      ⊘                     Vectorised halved
     Ｘ                      Vectorised raised to power
               Ｎ            Input as a number
    ∕                       Vectorised divide by
                 ⁵          Literal `5`
                ₂           Square root
   Ｅ              ⎇μ⁻⁰λλ    Negate the second element
  Σ                         Sum the elements
⭆¹                          Stringify
```

The version of Charcoal on TIO doesn't really support complex numbers, but as it happens the `Power` of a negative number to a floating-point value will return a complex result; I just have to be careful not to use operations such as `Negate` and `Cast` where Charcoal will get confused as to which overload to use.

18 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO:

```
Ｉ↨∕Ｘ⊘⊕⟦±₂⁵₂⁵⟧Ｎ₂⁵±¹
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjfbA4oy80o0nBOLSzScEotTNVwyyzJTUjUC8stTizQ8EnPKUlM0PPOSi1JzU_NKgOxov9T0xJJUjeDC0sSi1KD8_BINU01NHQUUfixIxDOvoLTErzQ3CWgQhgogH2qQoSYQWC8pTkouhjpqebSSblmOUuxiAz1TiAgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The version of Charcoal on ATO can use "base -1" conversion to take the difference of a list of two complex numbers saving 5 bytes and also can directly cast a complex number to string saving a further 1 byte. (Note that the difference has the opposite sign to the TIO code so I've swapped the two list elements to compensate.)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ØpC,$*÷5½¤I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjAJnHRWtw9tND@09tMTz/@H2R01rtA2ObDR4uGOezpGuY11RbkARawelQ1vd///XNTTQUTDUUdA111Ew1lEw0DPVUTDVA7LMQSxdQzBpqWdgpqMAJC2BHCM9UxOQGktLkDYzPQNjoGoLPRNzIwA)

<s>Need to find where the 1 byte is :c</s> 1 byte found thanks to Unrelated String :D

Comment: I was about to post this myself, but -1 if you just move the `I` to the end (no need for `µ`)

Comment: @UnrelatedString ah, I knew the chain break had to have been an unnecessary waste of bytes. thanks :D

Comment: [Also 11 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//w5hwQyzCpCpJw7c1wr3CpP87w4fDhmkkw6ZyNf//MC41), using niladic chains :P

Comment: [Also also 11 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjALnY2u0Dm83PbT30BJPv/@H2w@3ZR5eVmR6uO3h7m6uw@2PmtZE/v@va2igY6ija65jrGOgZ6pjqmesYw6kdQ1BhKWegZkOkLDU0TXSMzUBylpaAhWb6RkYG@tY6JmYGwEA). Note that `IN` could just as well be `_/`, and the `N` could also go before the `¤`. Smells vaguely like golfing potential

Comment: [(forgot to mention this third variation)](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjAJn52NrtA5vNz2099ASz/@H2w@3ZR5eVmR6uO3h7m6uw@2PmtZE/v@va2igY6ija65jrGOgZ6pjqmesYw6kdQ1BhKWegZkOkLDU0TXSMzUBylpaAhWb6RkYG@tY6JmYGwEA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```ruby
->n{((-p=(1-s=5**0.5)/2)**-n-p**n)/s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxb4QwDIX3/gokFkCKz3ZiJxnoWKlr14qlUm8rQnfqUFX97TQk0AKZHOvze36@fb59zdd@No/jd9OYqW/I3HvpOgRpL9x2nRnN1HVje7n/zHVVjdXxvbw3T2Oby@ePpXyYquurIRyWVl0gI/I3gBmgofzqrU0nwPjhAJA9AfaswCcgJRgOQGpoCJrWQbBCEjImYI@YgBd0kgeQA7uM@ZMaKQipasGIidbghduZMnmO2TQyuqJmIqAO/5h1YL0En7CkK@o0Y4mKezUrkFbLp0imSOKLGoO44WBqmXE5SFoHlbekMdIe8xBVmFc19GsEBbTpJhtmAmAQ9BkLzvpiGsB53qmxglWlkjSJic6/)

With thanks to Dingus for a 1-byte improvement, and Att for a 1-byte improvement and a correction.

Uses the fact that ϕ-1 = 1/ϕ

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZAxb4QwDIX3/gokFkCKz3ZiJxnoWKlr14qlUm8rQnfqUFX97TQk0AKZHOvze36@fb59zdd@No/jd9OYqW/I3HvpOgRpL9x2nRnN1HVje7n/zHVVjdXxvbw3T2Oby@ePpXyYquurIRyWVl0gI/I3gBmgofzqrU0nwPjhAJA9AfaswCcgJRgOQGpoCJrWQbBCEjImYI@YgBd0kgeQA7uM@ZMaKQipasGIidbghduZMnmO2TQyuqJmIqAO/5h1YL0En7CkK@o0Y4mKezUrkFbLp0imSOKLGoO44WBqmXE5SFoHlbekMdIe8xBVmFc19GsEBbTpJhtmAmAQ9BkLzvpiGsB53qmxglWlkjSJic6/)

Comment: \$(-\phi)^{-n}\$ also gets the sign of the imaginary part wrong

Comment: @att thanks for the 1 byte improvement and the correction! I shouldn't look at this site late at night.

Comment: @att The conjugate is a valid branch cut of Binet's formula.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 65 bytes

```javascript
with(Math)f=x=>[(q=5**.5,q*=(++q/2)**x)/5-cos(x*=PI)/q,-sin(x)/q]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5Ba4MwGIbv/oochCYao9amTiTdaYMdBrs7oanV6RBjNDhB/O0ubXXnfafne973g@@bD7zPuqpVTiOu@bL8VKqE71yVqGAjOyVQMmpZhGJpMWjb0t0jyxqRS51M9HC02McbciV2@qqBWst0UYCBxHB8D@jBBgD@Ck64mWADj9AHUBI8IFyN428QEe94jzREd7Mn9LBeRZF/M0fiBcHNPJFDuMdGGhuKFKJ74VkJB8BOYNJhnSuQcAwuqX6xgAOKV9nqnRMlXqsxv0KKSJe3Nc9y6H6SZ882XQx2u7@21O3Lv9qZaHpR56QWX/BsTu0MbGBOcq7OOp5RvPwC)

- -1 byte by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)
- -1 byte by [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)

Simply a translation of given formula

$$ q = \sqrt5\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}\right)^x $$

$$ F_x=\frac{q}{5}-\frac{\left(-1\right)^x}{q}=\left(\frac{q}{5}-\frac{\cos\left(\pi x\right)}{q}\right) + \left(-\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{q}\right)\cdot i $$

Nothing special here.

I believe it is wrong language to use here. Use some languages with complex numbers support would be a better idea.

Comment: Can save another byte with `q**-x` instead of `--q**x`

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 36 bytes

```
[ φ over ^ 1 φ - rot ^ - 5 √ / ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwAATvvmI/kJg2TWv1AeLFi3gShRBTLLVJTVJBxKv4Bj/lH/xIjXqZ3WWXraQK1g3r1WI5n6LRzugjWhkOP9CqNyrU1vh/7E2t7F6jczqES@dqE@D1qddGaY/Z6AqSMCQgBTgYFRCUo4hKki9KynJElCApFVlsyzKOc8o4x4RmRYrbsMHrDnvWDrv4FD2BsyEGAoH344kxtkMrO/ggVUOHDw)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a number as input and leaves a number as output. Factor seamlessly promotes floats and rational numbers to complex numbers when necessary (denoted by `C{ real imaginary }`). Assuming `0.5` is on top of the data stack when this quotation is called...

- `φ` Push phi, the golden ratio, to the data stack.

  **Stack:** `0.5 1.618033988749895`
- `over` Put a copy of NOS (next on stack) at TOS (top of stack).

  **Stack:** `0.5 1.618033988749895 0.5`
- `^` Raise NOS to the TOS power.

  **Stack:** `0.5 1.272019649514069`
- `1` Push `1` to the data stack.

  **Stack:** `0.5 1.272019649514069 1`
- `φ` Push phi to the data stack.

  **Stack:** `0.5 1.272019649514069 1 1.618033988749895`
- `-` Subtract TOS from NOS.

  **Stack:** `0.5 1.272019649514069 -0.6180339887498949`
- `rot` Take the data stack object third from the top and move it to TOS.

  **Stack:** `1.272019649514069 -0.6180339887498949 0.5`
- `^` Raise NOS to the TOS power.

  **Stack:** `1.272019649514069 C{ 4.813788842079551e-17 0.7861513777574233 }`
- `-` Subtract TOS from NOS.

  **Stack:** `C{ 1.272019649514069 -0.7861513777574233 }`
- `5` Push `5` to the data stack.

  **Stack:** `C{ 1.272019649514069 -0.7861513777574233 } 5`
- `√` Take the square root of TOS.

  **Stack:** `C{ 1.272019649514069 -0.7861513777574233 } 2.23606797749979`
- `/` Divide NOS by TOS.

  **Stack:** `C{ 0.568864481005783 -0.3515775842541429 }`

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

```
%:@5%~[:-/(-:1+(,-)%:5)&^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Va0cTFXroq109TV0rQy1NXR0NVWtTDXV4v5rcqUmZ@QrpCnEGxrAmIYwhoGeKYxpjmDGG@qZ/gcA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java + Apache Commons Math, <s>138</s> <s>136</s> 134 bytes

```
n->{var a=Math.sqrt(5);return new org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex(.5-a/2).pow(n).negate().add(Math.pow(a/2+.5,n)).divide(a);}
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Original Original Original VI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792).*

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718).*

Comment: Not using `b` may save a couple bytes: `n->{var a=Math.sqrt(5);return new org.apache.commons.math3.complex.Complex(1-a/2+.5).pow(n).negate().add(Math.pow(a/2+.5,n)).divide(a);}`

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI Good observation.

Comment: I know nothing about this implementation, but any reason to use `1-a/2-.5` instead of `.5-a/2`?

Comment: @tsh Thanks. I somehow missed that.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Complex results are returned as \$Re\$`J`\$Im\$.

```apl
-/s÷⍨(2÷⍨1(+,-)s←√5)*⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X1e/@PD2R70rNIzAlKGGto6uZvGjtgmPOmaZamo96lr0Pw3E6@171NX8qHfNo94th9YbP2qb@KhvanCQM5AM8fAM/p@ma2igAARcaQoKhlCGrjlMxBjGMNAzhTBM9YwhDHOoiK4hjGGpZ2AGlgIyLMEiRnqmJlBdlpaGIBEzPQNjY5CIhZ6JuREA)

`(`…`)*⊢` raise the following value to the power of the argument:

`√5` square root of five: \$\sqrt5\$

`s←` store that as `s` and return the value: \$\sqrt5\$

`1(+,-)` that, added to and subtracted from one: \$1±\sqrt5\$

`2÷⍨` half of that: \$1±\sqrt5\over2\$

Now we have \$\left(\frac{1±\sqrt5}2\right)^n\$

`s÷⍨` divide that by `s`: \$\left(\frac{1±\sqrt5}2\right)^n\over\sqrt5\$

`-/` the difference between them: \${\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^n\over\sqrt5}-{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^n\over\sqrt5}\$

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 73 bytes

```
=LET(q,5^0.5*((5^0.5+1)/2)^A1,a,PI()*A1,IF({1,0},q/5-COS(a)/q,-SIN(a)/q))
```

Using [tsh's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223003/101349)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 43 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##lU/baoQwEH33K@Yx6eri5KKrIV9StrDY2AbcWKztQ3/eziTPCy1yJnPmXMB12m/f4TjmrzTtcU2Q/CTuskp@28JMm1v8Z/wJItUo3bxuED2OSxU8nu3pbJ9Eg/IljmpcXBKhHqUvz2kLH/fbLpKIxOolpLf9XQTJNSG9ZhyTeFZgoIOLgxYUwThAWiyYq6xIZqIdeSxYR8YHAkcbLMpfGvnAdX1BsWQUkwba6QBIBTSpTRnQCL3i2bWAA@fhwiIMNC30jqnJR0UODbr7T12bw9jRn5ACjRoeFiKZ@WsUx7DA5RMTdZXHLw)

```
p=.5+sqrt(5/4);F=@(n)(p^n-(1-p)^n)/sqrt(5);
```

F is an anonymous function that you plug n into.

Comment: I think the link may be incorrect (different code). Also, you can replace `sqrt(5/4)` by `5^.5/2`, and reuse `5^.5` that to save a few bytes. Also, the `;` is not necessary, because the output is the argument returned by the function, not STDOUT: https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/0NY0Ts/UusBWz1S7UN/I2s3WQSNPU6MgLk9Xw1C3QDMuT1O/8L@bhqmeseZ/AA