# Block of digits

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity

Output/print this block of text:

```
1234567890
2468013579
3691470258
4815926037
5049382716
6172839405
7306295184
8520741963
9753108642
0987654321
```

Acceptable formats include:

- Trailing newlines/whitespace
- List of strings
- List of lists of characters
- List of lists of integers

However, list of integers is not acceptable because the last line is not an integer.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Answer (score 20):

### Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
Mod[1##,11]~Mod~10&~Array~{10,10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv4fUJSZV6LvoPHfNz8l2lBZWcfQMLYOyK4zNFCrcywqSqysqzY00DE0qP2v@R8A) (Using Mathics.)

The cell at 1-based index `(x,y)` has value `((x*y) % 11) % 10`

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```python
n=10
while n:print('00987654321'*n)[n::n];n-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/W0ICrPCMzJ1Uhz6qgKDOvREPdwMDSwtzM1MTYyFBdK08zOs/KKi/WOk/X1vD/fwA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and amazing first answer! We hope you'll stick around and contribute more :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions thanx :)))

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```python
n=1
exec"print('01234567890'*n)[n::n];n+=1;"*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WkCu1IjVZqaAoM69EQ93A0MjYxNTM3MLSQF0rTzM6z8oqL9Y6T9vW0FpJy9Dg/38A)

Comment: nice exec use..

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
⁵×þ`%‘%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49bD0w/vS1B91DBD9f9/AA)

Uses Martin's algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to Luis. I keep forgetting the `&` is a shortcut for duplicating and transposing.

```
10:&*11\10\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39DASk3L0DDG0CDm/38A)

Using @Martin's algorithm: `x*y % 11 % 10`

**Explanation:**

```
10            % Pust 10 to the stack. Stack: 1
  :           % 1-based range. Stack: [1 2 3 ... 10]
   &          % Duplicate range. Stack: [1 2 3 ... 10],[1 2 3 ... 10]
              % Transpose last range. Stack [1 2 3 ... 10],[1;2;3 ...10]
    *         % Multiply with broadcasting. Stack: [1 2 3 ...;2 4 6...] (10-by-10 array)
     11       % Push 11 to the stack. Stack [1 2 3 ...;2 4 6 ...], 11
       \      % Modulus. 
        10    % Push 10 to the stack.
          \   % Modulus
              % Implicit display
```

Same bytecount:

```
10t:&*11\w\
```

Comment: You can save a byte replacing `t!*` by`&*`

Comment: @LuisMendo double backticks if you have a backslash at the end of code snippet in comments.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks! I never remember how that works, so I went for the easy way :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo yeah it's a bit confusing with posts and comments using different syntax.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo! That's not in the docs is it?

Comment: It is. The help for `*` says `If 1 input: a second input is used given by the first transposed`. And the notation `1-- (2 / 1);  1` for `*` means that `&` specifies 1 input (see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93790/36398) for explanation of this notation). Note that the meaning of `&` is function-specific

Answer (score 4):

### [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
10|11|∘.×⍨⍳10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdJTM9s8QpJz85@7@hQY2hYc2jjhl6h6c/6l3xqHezoQFIyX@EGgA)

A port of [my Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128361/8478).

```apl
      ∘.×⍨      ⍝ Multiplication table of...
          ⍳10   ⍝ The list from 1 to 10.
   11|          ⍝ mod 11.
10|             ⍝ mod 10.
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (17 bytes)

```
A,:)_f{f*Bf%Af%N}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=A%2C%3A)_f%7Bf*Bf%25Af%25N%7D)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Turns out this was my 200 (undeleted) answer here :)

Looks like this is the same formula [Martin spotted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128361/58974).

```
Aõ
£®*X%B%A
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QfUKo64qWCVCJUE=&input=LVI=) (`-R` flag for visualisation purposes only)

- 4 bytes saved thanks to [Luke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63774/luke) pointing out that returning an array of arrays was permissible.

---

### Explanation

```
Aõ    :Generate an array of integers from 1 to 10, inclusive.
£     :Map over each element in the array, returning...
®     :Another map of the same array, which...
*X    :Multiplies the current element of the inner function by the current element of the outer function...
%B    :Modulus 11...
%A    :Modulus 10.
      :Implicit output of resulting 2D array
```

Comment: Beat me to it... You can drop the last two characters, and instead use the `-R` flag

Comment: Even better, drop the last four characters. It seems that's allowed...

Comment: Yup, looks like you're right, thanks, @Luke :)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>70 64</s> 56 bytes

```
_=>[...1e9+''].map((_,a,b)=>b.map((_,c)=>-~a*++c%1‌​1%10))
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Shaggy and 8 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

Comment: 66 bytes: `_=>[...a=Array(10)].map((_,x)=>[...a].map((_,y)=>(x+1)*++y%11%10))`. You save me 4 bytes, I save you 4 bytes :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You also fixed a bug, so I shaved another 2 bytes of your solution ;-)

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by using the 3rd parameter of the callback in the first `map()` and 3 more bytes by using `1e9+''` instead of `Array(10)`. That leads to `_=>[...1e9+''].map((_,x,a)=>a.map((_,y)=>-~x*++y%11%10))`.

Comment: @Arnauld: Thanks for the `1e9` trick. I didn't know that one. I did think about using the third argument, but for some reason I didn't use it.

Comment: I've recently compiled a list of similar tricks [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128411/58563).

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 59 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
10$*
1
,1$`
,1+
$_¶
(?<=(¶?.+)+)1
$#1$*
1{10}1?

,(1*)
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy9BARYvLkEvHUCUBSGhzqcQf2salYW9jq3Fom72etqa2piGXirIhSFG1oUGtoT0Xl46GoZYml4qe4f//AA)

#### Explanation

Another implementation of the **... % 11 % 10** algorithm. The fun part of doing it with a regex is that we can take care of both modulo computations at once.

```
10$*
```

Initialise the string to ten `1`s.

```
1
,1$`
```

Replace each of those with a comma, a one, and the prefix in front of that one. This gives `,1,11,...,1111111111`, i.e. a unary range.

```
,1+
$_¶
```

Now replace each of the range elements with the entire string followed by a linefeed. This gives us a 10x10 grid of unary numbers indicating the current column.

```
(?<=(¶?.+)+)1
$#1$*
```

Match each `1` and determine which row it's on by repeating group one that many times. Replace the `1` with that many `1`s. This multiplies the values in each row by the row's 1-based index.

```
1{10}1?
```

Now let's do **mod 11, mod 10** in one step. To do **mod 11**, we'd normally just remove all `1{11}` from the string to be left with the remainders. And then we'd remove `1{10}` after that. But if we just remove ten `1`s plus another if possible, the regex engine's greediness will do **mod 11** for us as long as possible, and if not, then it'll try at least **mod 10**.

```
,(1*)
$.1
```

Finally, we just convert each number to decimal by replacing it with its length.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
11GTLN*11%T%})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0NA9xMdPy9BQNUS1VvP/fwA)

Uses Martin's algorithm, as usual.

Comment: Oh, there's an algorithm for that pattern. That explains why I'm 30 bytes above the average answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 43 bytes

```
l=[1..10]
f=[[x*i`mod`11`mod`10|i<-l]|x<-l]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>30 29</strike> 19 bytes

```
Ｆχ«ＦχＩ﹪﹪×⁺¹ι⁺¹κ¹¹χ⸿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nmXn2w@tBlPv96x8v3MVEB2e/qhx16Gd53ZCKCA@tPN8@6Md@///BwA)

Uses [Martin's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128361/70347).

- 10 bytes saved thanks to Neil, proving once more that I have still so much to learn...

Comment: You don't need trailing `»`s and while you can use `ω` instead of `””` you can save a whole bunch of bytes by using `⸿` as this then becomes `Ｆχ«ＦχＩ﹪﹪×⁺¹ι⁺¹κ¹¹χ⸿`. (Before I knew about `⸿` I would have suggested `Ｊ⁰ι` which would still have saved a number of bytes.)

Comment: @Neil The `⸿` is the reverse operator, what does it do at the end of your code without arguments? Is it documented?

Comment: No, `⮌` is the Reverse operator, `⸿` is the `move cursor to start of next line` character (like `¶` but can be in a separate string).

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 84 bytes

```java
o->{String r="";for(int x=0,y;++x<11;r+="\n")for(y=0;++y<11;r+=x*y%11%10);return r;}
```

Uses the same algorithm as [*@MartinEnder*'s Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128361/52210): 1-indexed `x*y%11%10`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY7BbsIwEETv/YpVJCS7gSg@u@YPgAPHtgdjTOXgrCNng2KhfHtqhKWdw86s9k2nH3oXBovd9b4ar8cRDtrh8wPAIdl408bC8bUCnCk6/APDTpfOGoLAZfaXrDwjaXIGjoCgYA27/bOcR1VV8hYiy/9gVu02ybqev4SQsVbVD1b8FSbVZjsVe/5MGyE2ouUyWpoiQpTLKt@kYbr4TCrAR3BX6HNl9uZ9/4LmpW8ayfZNmKgZckQeGTaG4eQ9L9WX9R8)

```java
o->{                     // Unused Object parameter and String return-type
  String r="";           //  Result-String
  for(int x=0,y;++x<11;  //  Loop (1) from 1 to 11 (exclusive)
      r+="\n")           //    And append a new-line after every iteration
    for(y=0;++y<11;      //   Inner loop (2) from 1 to 11 (exclusive)
      r+=x*y%11%10       //    And append the result-String with `x*y%11%10`
    );                   //   End of inner loop (2)
                         //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;              //  Return result-String
}                        // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>58</s> 52 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to offcialaimm.*

Uses Martin's algorithm which I have no understanding of how he came up with it so fast. o0

```python
r=range(1,11)
print[[x*y%11%10for y in r]for x in r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8i2KDEvPVXDUMfQUJOroCgzryQ6ukKrUtXQUNXQIC2/SKFSITNPoSgWxKyAMP//BwA)

Comment: Shorthand `r=range(1,11)` saves 6 bytes

Comment: Part of the reason I spotted the formula so quickly is [this math.SE question of mine and orlp's comment there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769877/50421).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
mme%*kd11STST
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mme%25%2akd11STST&debug=0)

-1 thanks to [KarlKastor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56557/karlkastor).

*Let's duuuuuuupe!*

Comment: Save one byte if you use `e` instead of `% T`

Comment: @KarlKastor ...and I was remembering it ._.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 19 bytes

```r
1:10%o%1:10%%11%%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/39DK0EA1XxVMqRoaArHB//8A)

The least "R"-looking bit of R code I have ever written. Uses the same algorithm as [Martin Ender's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128361/66252) (and almost all the other answers as well). `x %o% y` is the same as `outer(x, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 70 bytes

```c
f(x,y){for(x=0;x++<10;puts(""))for(y=0;y++<10;putchar(x*y%11%10+48));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0KnUrM6Lb9Io8LWwLpCW9vG0MC6oLSkWENJSVMTJF4JFK@EiydnJAKValWqGhqqGhpom1hoalrX/s9NzMzTABqjAeIAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>93</s> 85 bytes

```
10$*T
M!&`T+
m`$
;110$*T10$*
1
09876543210
m`(?<=^\1;\1{0,9}(T+))T
C
(?<!C.{108})\S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy9BARSuEy1dRLSFEmys3QYXL2hAsBCK4DLkMLC3MzUxNjI0MDYCyGvY2tnExhtYxhtUGOpa1GiHampohXM5cQHFFZ71qQwOLWs2YYK7//wE)

Comment: 71 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy9BARYvLkOvQNmcVdesQrphybS4VNRiEc7lCuAwsLczNTE2MjQwNuOIObavRsLdRdNarNjSwrNWMCeb6/x8A "Retina – Try It Online") No idea where the magic number of 109 derives from through.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 54 bytes

```php
for(;9>=$y++||9>=$x+=$y=print"
";)echo($x+1)*$y%11%10;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKwt7WxVKrW1a2pAjAptIMe2oCgzr0SJS8laMzU5I18DKGqoqaVSqWpoqGpoYP3/PwA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 56 bytes

```php
for(;$x++<=9;print"
")for($y=0;$y++<=9;)echo$x*$y%11%10;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVKrS1bWwtrQuKMvNKlLiUNEGiKpW2BtYqlRAZzdTkjHyVCi2VSlVDQ1VDA@v//wE)

Comment: You can drop the brackets `()`.

Comment: -2 bytes: `for(;<0>$y++||10>$x+=$y=print"\n";)echo($x+1)*$y%11%10;`

Comment: ... or `for($x=1;11>++$y||11>$x+=$y=print"\n";)echo$x*$y%11%10;`

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 17 bytes

```
[|?[|?a*b%11%z';
```

This, of course, uses Martin's Method. It translates to [this QBasic code](https://repl.it/JCEg/0).

### Explanation

```
[|               FOR A = 1 to 10 ([ starts a FOR loop, | delimits the list of arguments; 
                 a FOR loop with 0 args loops from 1 to 10 by default with increment 1.
  ?              PRINT a newline
   [|            Start a second FOR loop from 1-10, iterator b
     ?           PRINT
      a*b%11%z   the result of Martin's formula.
              '; and suppress newlines/tabs/spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 81 bytes

```c#
_=>{var r="";for(int x=0,y;++x<11;r+="\n")for(y=0;++y<11;r+=x*y%11%10);return r;}
```

Same algorithm as most of the other answers and essentially the C# port of [@Kevins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128378/38550) Java answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 79 bytes

```
12345678902468013579369147025848159260375049382716
.*
$&$&
O$^50>`.

.{10}
$&¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcirEYNAFABA/@q4QSBu3v9jaCEdZEAgYiIycQxtpYA0drByP/v39d7GAGJR88hCVk8ksSjxIg1kS02yYkcJQy1JDnLoM7SpTfBoT8Nl7QD9IDzv/P/GuAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>37</s> 24 bytes

```
10,{){\)*11%10%}+10,%}%`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39BAp1qzOkZTy9BQ1dBAtVYbKKBaq5rw/z8A)

-13 thanks to a clever trick [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender) suggested.

Comment: if you turn it into a full program (`{` --> `;`, `}` --> `\``), you can at least drop the first `[`.

Comment: It's a lot shorter to use a simple nested loop instead of the zip technique though: `{){\)*11%10%}+10,/n}10,/`

Comment: @MartinEnder Umm...you seem to be overusing `/`. ;)

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh I see what you did...you used `int blk +` -> `{int space contents-of-blk}`.

Comment: @MartinEnder ok I've implemented your `+` trick...although I altered your code a bit

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes

```c
f(n,t){for(n=11;++n<121;putchar(t?t%10+48:10))t=n/11*n%11;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@nRLM6Lb9II8/W0NBaWzvPxtDI0LqgtCQ5I7FIo8S@RNXQQNvEwsrQQFOzxDZP39BQK08VqLL2f25iZp4GUK@GJpADAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 15 bytes

```
TD]UMha*11%`e)P
```

[Try it here!](http://199.195.254.22/?code=TD%5DUMha%2a11%25%60e%29P&warnings=0)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 13 bytes

```
TS F~u0+*i>i%
```

[Try it here!](http://199.195.254.22/?code=TS+F%7Eu0%2B%2ai%3Ei%25)

```
TS            -  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   F~u0+*i>i% - for i in ^:
    ~u0+      -     "01234567890"
        *     -    ^ * i
         i>   -   ^[i:]
           i% -  ^[::i]
```

Answer (score 0):

### TECO, 45 bytes

```teco
1un@i/
/10<@i/01234567890/jl10<qnc0a^t>jtl%n>
```

A (fairly) straightforward implementation of Rod's Python answer.

```teco
1un           !initialize register n to 1!
@i/<nl>/      !insert a newline!
10<           !loop for 10 rows!
@i/01234567890/  !insert the mysterious string of digits!
j             !move point to start of buffer!
l             !move forward past the newline!
10<           !loop for 10 digits on a line!
qnc           !move point forward by n characters!
0a^t          !print the character at point!
>             !end inner loop!
j             !move point to start of buffer!
t             !print (empty) line!
l             !move to start of digit string!
%n            !increment register n (for next line)!
>             !end outer loop!
```

Using <ESC>-terminated inserts and a control character for the ^T command would save another <s>three</s> five bytes, at the expense of readability.

Using Martin's mod-11/mod-10 formula actually makes it longer at 43 bytes using controls for ^A and ^T, mostly because TECO doesn't have a mod operator.

```teco
0ur10<%run10<qn-10"g-11%n'qn\r0a^Tqr%n>^a
^A>
```

Mod 11 is done in an ongoing fashion by incrementing the number in qn by -11 whenever it exceeds 10. The `qn\r0a^T` sequence inserts the number in the editing buffer as decimal digits, reverses past the last digit, retrieves it from the buffer and types it, essentially doing mod-10.

I expected it to be shorter.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 27 bytes

```
1":(10|11|*&>:)"0/~@(i.@9:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqCjYKBgBcS6egrOQTo@bv8Nlaw0DA1qDA1rtNTsrDSVDPTrHDQy9RwsrTT/a3KlJmfkK6QpqKv/BwA)

Uses the same trick as in [Martin Ender's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128361/31957).