# Distribute a number into a list of values as equal as possible whose sum is equal to that number

Tags: code-golf, number

Probably a simple code-golf challenge. Given 2 positive integers `m` and `n`, make a list of `n` values that are positive integers whose sum is equal to the number `m`. Either all values in the output are the same value or the difference is exactly 1.

**Examples**

For example

- `m=6` and `n=3` would become `2, 2, 2`
- `m=7` and `n=3` would become `2, 2, 3` or `2, 3, 2` or  `3, 2, 2`
- `m=7` and `n=2` would become `3, 4` or `4, 3`
- `m=7` and `n=1` would become `7`
- `m=7` and `n=8` would generate an error because the sum of 8 positive integers cannot be 7.
- `m=10` and `n=4` would become `3, 3, 2, 2` or any other permutation

**Rules**

- Both input and output is only about positive integers.
- Either all values in the output are the same value or the difference is exactly 1.
- The order of the values in the list is not important.
- The sum of the values in the list is equal to `m`.
- When it's not solvable, generate an error or a false value (in case of m=7 and n=8 for example).
- As a result of the other rules `m=8` and `n=3` would generate any of the permutations of `3, 3, 2` (not `2, 2, 4`)

**The winner**

This is code-golf, so the shortest valid answer – measured in bytes – wins.

Comment: I'm assuming zero is not positive?

Comment: Indeed it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Order-theoretic_properties

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Strictly speaking, zero is never positive.

Comment: @aras I'm no mathematician but from what I've read up it usually depends on context. Some say it is unsigned, some both positive and negative, some positive etc.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder meanwhile, in java (and floating point in general), `float a = -0f, b = 0f;
        System.out.println(a == b);
        System.out.println(a + "," + b);`... produces `true` and `-0.0,0.0`. See, positive 0 and negative 0 are clearly two distinct number... the implementation says so!

Comment: Suggested test case: `m=8`, `n=3`, which -- I think -- should be any permutation of `3,3,2` (_not_ `2,2,4`).

Comment: @Arnauld. It is something that can be derived from the other rules, but it might help to show your test case. I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: suggested testcase `10 4`

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/280648/92517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia/blob/master/codepage.md)

```
…÷l¦
```

There's almost just a built-in for this...

#### Explanation

```
…     Get the range [0 .. m-1].
 ÷    Split into n roughly even length chunks. Throws an error if the number of chunks if 
       more than the list's length.
  l¦  Get the length of each chunk.
```

Comment: I thought there was a 4 byte solution too with 05AB1E. Now that it's gone, it makes it easier for me to decide. Congratulations and thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>48</s> 43 bytes

Returns `0` on error.

```python
lambda m,n:m/n and[m/n]*(n-m%n)+m%n*[m/n+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFXJ88qVz9PITEvJRpIx2pp5OnmquZpagMJLZCItmHs/5KiSisuzvKMzJxUhZCi0lQgh7OgKDOvRCFNQyszr6C0RENTkyu1Ijm1oETB1d/NtagovwioqCCxuPi/mY4xlzkYGwGxIRBbcBkaGOhYAAA)

---

#### 41 bytes (with @xnor's trick)

Throws `NameError` on error.

```python
lambda m,n:[m/n or _]*(n-m%n)+m%n*[m/n+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpPC4IwGIfP26fYJZx/IjUoETrasS7dSmLWRMG9jtdJ@enXsoIOzw9@D4@eTNNDauvdxXZCVXfBVAT5Wa2A9ciuZcBhqRbgh26Ctw6T0hqcckoeTdtJdsJRukM@jhCNLRhW86AFPRru@07K501qww5CyQKxx7/Qm4VHv0lx3P8KLYbBbqI13c6kjsSR0SSOo@wF)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
:gie!Xs
```

When there is no solution the output is an array containing at least one zero, which is [falsy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398) in MATL.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yo9M1Uxovj/f0MDLhMA)

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `m = 10` and `n = 4`.

```
:      % Implicitly input m. Push [1 2 ... m]
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
g      % Logical: convert nonzeros to 1
       % STACK: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
i      % Input n
       % STACK: [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1], 4
e      % Reshape into matrix with n rows, padding with zeros
       % STACK: [1 1 1;
                 1 1 1;
                 1 1 0;
                 1 1 0]
!      % Transpose
       % STACK: [1 1 1 1;
                 1 1 1 1;
                 1 1 0 0]
Xs     % Sum of each column. Implicitly display
       % STACK: [3 3 2 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
#>#2&&Last@IntegerPartitions@##1&
```

**input**

> [63, 11]

**output**

> {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5}

outputs ***False*** when it's not solvable

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
m%n|m>=n=map(`div`n)[m..m+n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1c1rybXzjbPNjexQCMhJbMsIU8zOldPL1c7T9cw9n9uYmaegq0CUNJXoaAoM69EQQXEUdAozUsuLSqqVNBQ1dRUiNYw0zHW1NEwh5JGYNIQSBoa6JiAORaasf8B)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes after applying NDD<sup>1</sup>

```
¿÷ＮＮＩＥＩη÷⁺ＩθιＩη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///Q/sPb3@9ZB0Yr3@9ZCiTPbT@8/VHjLhBrx7mdYIH//w0NFIwB)

Outputs nothing if there is no solution. Link to the [verbose version](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8zTcMzr8QlsywzJRXIKigt8SvNTUot0tDUQeFpaioEFGXmlWg4JxaXaPgmFkAYGZo6Cgj9jikpEOFCTZ1MoAxUCQhY//9vaKBg/l@37L9ucQ4A).

<sup>1</sup>NDD = Neil-Driven Development.

My previous answer:

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>32 27 24</strike> 20 bytes

```
ＮμＮν¿÷μνＩＥν⁺÷μν‹ι﹪μν
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nnXn9oCIvYf2H95@bs@5ve/3rHy/Z@m5vY8ad0EEHjXsPLfz/c5VIPb//@YKpgA)

Outputs nothing if there is no solution. Link to the [verbose version](https://tio.run/##XYs7CsMwEAX7nGLLFciQkNKVSRpDbHIFxZLxgrQy@vj6G6ULnm6G95bNpCUaLzLyXstcw8clDKq//Ds3pxVw5PKkg6zDoIGVgnciLvgwueBkdmQNg7XnmYaXyxlJwxRt9bHV9v3Ri9yucJfukC77Lw).

Of course, I couldn't have golfed it down without Neil's help.

Comment: Removing the `Cast` operator works for some reason, but this isn't an ideal algorithm... I have a 16-byte solution.

Comment: @Neil Challenge accepted!

Comment: I like the predefined variable, but now knowing that `Cast` works on lists I'm down to 11 bytes...

Comment: @Neil And I'm still unable to use `Map`, how on Earth does it work??

Comment: `Map` is like the expression version of `for`, down to using the same loop variable. So in your example, rather than pushing an expression to a list each time, `Map` automatically collects them up and evaluates to the list of results.

Comment: @Neil OK, I got `Map` working (thank you!), but it seems I will have to completely change the algorithm if I want to achieve 11 bytes...

Comment: Another tip for you is that Python usually casts booleans to 0 or 1 for you, so you don't need a ternary this time. As for the smarter way, some of the other answers do have a better calculation.

Comment: @Neil I think I've found your 11-byte solution: `ＩＥＩη÷⁺ＩθιＩη`, but this does not address the case when `n > m` that must generate an error or a falsy value. Even so, the result with a previous `if` is shorter than what I have accomplished so far, so... updating!

Comment: Ah, you're right, that's how I accidentally got down to 11. With the `if` I'm back up to 16 like I said in the first place. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Neil found a 15-byte way to do it! :-)

Comment: Very clever! (I just double-checked and my 11 byte "solution" was in fact a rediscovery of my 16-byte solution but without the `if`. Oops!)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 33 bytes

```r
function(m,n)diff(trunc(0:n*m/n))
```

A port of Luis Mendo's [Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132126/67312). Pretty sad that this is almost 50% shorter than my previous answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jVydPMyUzLU2jpAgopGFglaeVq5@nqfk/TcNcx0LzPwA)

#### previous answer, 63 bytes:

```r
function(m,n,o=rep(m%/%n,n),d=m-sum(o))o+c(rep(0,n-d),rep(1,d))
```

An anonymous function that takes two (mandatory) arguments `m` and `n`, and two optional ones which are for golfing purposes. Returns a vector in increasing order. For failure, the first value will be `0`, which is falsey in R, since `if` only uses the first value of the vector (with a warning).

It is essentially equivalent to the following function:

```r
function(m,n){o=rep(m%/%n,n)
d=m-sum(o)
o+c(rep(0,n-d),rep(1,d))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JckxCoQwEAXQ3lOkEebjFxUEt0m7J/AGSQYEMxFdzx@R7R68s6qvelv4bcUk01j8mQ7J7dAaDYw@99edpQClC/LeSOsj@HJiBKrKNHJGo7Lwg2ZT@QtudWm/kvvWBw)

Comment: `pryr::f(diff(trunc(0:n*m/n)))` works and is shorter!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
:ȧœsL€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/qxPKjk4t9HjWt@f//v/l/YwA) Outputs nothing for falsy.

#### How it works

```
:ȧœsL€    Main link. Arguments: m (integer), n (integer)
:         Integer division. Yields 0 if m < n; a positive integer otherwise.
 ȧ        Logical AND. Yields 0 if m < n; m otherwise.
  œs      Split into n roughly equal groups. Since the left argument is an integer,
          this implicitly converts it to [1..m] (or [] for 0) before splitting.
    L€    Length of €ach. If the inputs were 7 and 3, the previous result would be
          [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7]], so this would give [3,2,2].
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 24 bytes

```matlab
@(m,n)diff(fix(0:m/n:m))
```

The code defines an anonymous function. The output is a numeric array (row vector). When there is no this array contains at least one zero, which is [falsy](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/QsFWIdpQwUjBWMEg1porM02hgktBISWzuEBDvaSotCSjUl2TKzWnOBUumpaYUwwWzEv5/x8A) in Octave.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjVydPMyUzLU0jLbNCw8AqVz/PKldT83@ahpmOsSZXmoY5jDKCUIYQygJEGRromGj@BwA)

#### Explanation

`0:m/n:m` produces an array of `n+1` values from `0` to `m` with step `m/n`. `fix` rounds each entry towards `0`, and `diff` computes consecutive differences.

As an example, here are all intermediate results for `m = 7`, `n = 3`:

```matlab
>> 0:m/n:m
ans =
         0    2.3333    4.6667    7.0000

>> fix(0:m/n:m)
ans =
     0     2     4     7

>> diff(fix(0:m/n:m))
ans =
     2     2     3
```

Comment: An array containing a zero is falsy. That seems like a stretch, but I'm don't know Octave either. Coming from Javascript with its coercions, I'd say why the hell not. +1 from me.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Thanks! It does sound strange if you come from other languages, but that's [how it is](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/QsFWIdpQwUjBWMEg1porM02hgktBISWzuEBDvaSotCSjUl2TKzWnOBUumpaYUwwWzEv5/x8A) in MATLAB/Octave

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>86</strike> <strike>82</strike> 71 bytes

```
using System.Linq;a=>b=>new int[b].Select((x,i)=>(i<a%b?1:0/(a/b))+a/b)
```

throws an error for invalid inputs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY9LSwMxEIDv@RVDQUhw3bYovrYbD0VFqSD04KH0kMRxGdhNMMn6QPrb16xULd7cOYRkMt/MNyYcGOexawPZCpbvIWJTsN1XviD7/Cc1d3WNJpKzIb9Gi55MwZipVQhw713lVQMfDFKEqCIZeHH0CHeKLA/Rp0arNShfBbGt6uOqtWZGNmY7t5tL2zbola6xT0gp4Sl9QgnfGOtUKXUpLb5Cqljpdb7E3o3zt4xEKTnN1J6@mJ5PxlyNtRD7/dlB8v0ZPU97uBrzB08R07q4tcxvXTIeZaPsayw/FvxQCFH8GzwZCk4ngh8NIs8EPx3q@gtu2Kb7BA)

-4 bytes thanks to *TheLethalCoder*

-11 bytes thanks to *OlivierGrégoire*

Comment: This is only a code snippet at the moment; you just need to wrap it in an anonymous function or `a=>b=>` at the start.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Hmm are you sure? Don't I need to add the `using System.Collections.Generic` if I return an `IEnumerable<int>`?

Comment: I got that wrong anyway because you're returning an array (I misread the first part of the ternary). But only if that shows in your code and seeing as the `IEnumerable<int>` would be in the function definition you won't need to include the `using`.

Comment: No, Your tip is still good since the code without .ToArray() still compiles.

Comment: I don't do much C# (not at all actually), but it looks to me that this is shorter: `a=>b=>new int[b].Select((x,i)=>(i<a%b?1:0/(a/b))+a/b)` (53 bytes). I reused, some ideas from my Java answer.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, he said if not possible you need to output 0 , false or error and without the first part which throws error it will return an array like `[0,0,0,0,0]` which doesn't really conform to that.

Comment: @LiefdeWen have you tried running it? I get an error, not a zero-filled array: `System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.` Seems good enough for me, doesn't it? The error happens in the second part!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You are right, sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>93</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> <s>86</s> 71 bytes

```hs
m!n|n<=m=e$m:(0<$[2..n])
e(a:b:x)|b<a=e$a-1:e(b+1:x)
e(a:x)=a:e x
e x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1cxrybPxjbXNlUl10rDwEYl2khPLy9WkytVI9EqyapCsybJJhEomahraJWqkaRtCBQCy1Vo2iZapSpUcAGxbcX/3MTMPNuCosy8EhULRYv/AA)

### Explanation

The main function here is `e`.  `e` will take a list and essentially run a rolling pin along it from left to right.  While there is an element in the list that is greater than its neighbor to the right we will move one from it to the right.

Now all we have to do is feed this function a sufficiently lopsided list and allow it to do the magic.  The list we will choose is just `m` followed by `n-1` zeros.  Since that is easy to make.

The last thing we need to do is make sure that the error case is handled.  For this we just throw a `Non-exhaustive patterns in function` error as long as `m>n`.

Comment: I think you can get rid of `error[]` by failing with a non-exhaustive pattern instead: `m!n|m>n=e$m:replicate(n-1)0`.

Comment: Also `(0<$[1..n-1])` is shorter than `replicate(n-1)0`.

Answer (score 2):

### TI-Basic, 23 bytes

```
:Prompt M,N
:N(M≥N
:int(Ans⁻¹randIntNoRep(M,M+N-1
```

Returns ERR:DIVIDE BY 0 on error

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 48 bytes

```
m#n|m>=n=iterate(\(a:b)->b++[a+1])(0<$[1..n])!!m
```

Start with a list of `n` zeros. Repeat `m` times: take the first element, add one and put it at the end of the list.

Fails with a pattern match error if `n < m`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1c5rybXzjbPNrMktSixJFUjRiPRKklT1y5JWzs6UdswVlPDwEYl2lBPLy9WU1Ex939uYmaegq1CSj6XgkJBUWZeiYKKgrmyGQrPBIVnjMIz/A8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>57 56 53</s> 41 bytes

```
m=>n=>m>=n&&[...Array(n)].map(_=>m++/n|0)
```

Answer now includes smarter way of creating the values. Thanks @Neil

**Usage**

```
f=m=>n=>m>=n&&[...Array(n)].map(_=>m++/n|0)

f(6)(3) // [2, 2, 2]
f(7)(3) // [3, 2, 2]
f(7)(2) // [4, 3]
f(7)(1) // [7]
f(7)(8) // false
f(8)(3) // [3, 3, 2]
```

**History**

First mine

```
(m,n)=>m>=n&&Array(n).fill(~~(m/n)).map((v,i)=>v+(i<m%n))

(m,n)=>m>=n&&Array(n).fill().map((v,i)=>~~(m/n)+(i<m%n))
```

Then added the spread operator and currying syntax tipped by @Arnauld

```
m=>n=>m>=n&&[...Array(n)].map((v,i)=>~~(m/n)+(i<m%n))
```

Comment: `_=>m++/n|0` saves a bunch of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.1, 62 bytes

```php
for([,$s,$n]=$argv;$n;)$s-=$r[]=$s/$n--^0;$r[0]?print_r($r):0;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c54597ef374eef5e40c48cb7411aebb0802ab077)

Comment: Clicked your link to the Sandbox, clicked Execute code and I got a Parse error.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek The sandbox defaults to PHP 7.0.3.

Comment: With other languages like Octave and MATL a zero in an array is considered falsy, but I don't believe this to be the case with php. I suppose the output has to be falsy within the rules of the language the program is written in.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 30 bytes

```
.M>.M/v.mR>[.]$_v%!?[R1+>v]|R=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fz9dOz1e/TC83yC5aL1YlvkxV0T46yFDbriy2Jsj2////xv8NDQE)

Takes inputs in reverse order (`n` is first input, `m` is second)

Divides `m` by `n`, duplicates the result `n` times, then loops through and increments one by one `m % n` times

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 71 bytes

```
@if %1 geq %2 for /l %%i in (1,1,%2)do @cmd/cset/an=(%1+%%i-1)/%2&echo(
```

`cmd/cset/a` doesn't output any separator, so I have to use `echo(` (`(` avoids printing `ECHO is on.`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda m,n:(m%n*[m/n+1]+[m/n or _]*n)[:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFXJ89KI1c1Tys6Vz9P2zBWG0Qr5BcpxMdq5WlGW@XF/i/PyMxJVQgpKk214uIsKaoEkpwFRZl5JQppGlqZeQWlJRqamlycqRXJqQUlCq7@bq5FRflFIFVJRamJ2TAZhDYlsAKl/2Y6xlzmYGwExIZAbMFlaGCgYwEA)

`NameError` when impossible.

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes**

```python
lambda m,n:[c/n for c in range(m,m+n,m>=n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcsxD4IwFATgmf6KFybQJgImQkhww9XFTR0KFmikj@alRPn1tZIYh@@WuzOLHSbMXFfd3Ch08xCgOZbXdofQTQQtKAQS2MtIc71Fro8Vxnf3GtQo4UKzLFlgafEZGFJooYs2Cs1sozhmgXy30lioz6eaaKLvqiEpnr/mfwvXQegOfM/yVealXuHlLE0SXnwA)

`ValueError` when impossible.

Comment: have never thought of using `NameError` to exit via error

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>80</s> <s>73</s> <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```java
n->m->{for(int i=n;i-->0/(m/n);)System.out.println(m++/n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBfT8IwFMXf9ylueGplK6BGjZO9GEx8MCbwSPZQy8Di@ifrHZGQffbZsTGI4aW9/d1zz2m75TseGZvp7eqnlsqaAmHrGStR5mxdaoHSaHYTB7b8yqUAkXPn4INLDYcAoKMOOfptZ@QKlO@RBRZSb5Yp8GLj6FEK8K7xrXN88fWr0a5UWZHAelrrKFFRclibgkiNIKc6llGUjEdEjTSN6WLvMFPMlMist8ZcEzUcNq2qjo/uHi5Tn4iZQwfTLhPgAPAQwh1U4Rk8XgG3/8HTJZiMQ7g/gapN7C7bZT63ybQPxmLf117MuLX5njSi5SSljAuRWWzP45TGvfLKU/tuBYKj@AYy@22m/U9CRi9SrswOZvP553xwtghOaxW0df0H)

Note, for currying purpose, `m` and `n` are reversed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
efqlTeQ./hQ
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=efqlTeQ.%2FhQ&input=%5B10%2C+4%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B6%2C+3%5D%0A%5B7%2C+3%5D%0A%5B7%2C+2%5D%0A%5B7%2C+1%5D%0A%5B7%2C+8%5D%0A%5B10%2C+4%5D%0A%5B8%2C+3%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
S`?ø▼Ẋ-mo÷³*⁰Θḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9odXNr//9TYD/DuOKWvOG6ii1tb8O3wrMq4oGwzpjhuKP///82/zEw) A port of [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132126). Takes `n` followed by `m` as arguments. Outputs an empty list when no solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
KE?>KQ0lMcK*d
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KE%3F%3EKQ0lMcK%2Ad&input=10%0A4&debug=0&input_size=4) Output `0` on error.

**Cheating, 6 bytes**

```
lMcE*d
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lMcE%2Ad&input=10%0A4&debug=0&input_size=4) The array contains a `0` on error. Sadly this isn't falsy in [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth).

**Explanation**

```
KE?>KQ0lMcK*dQ    # Implicit input Q for m
KE                # Store n in K
           *d     # Generate a string of length Q containing only spaces
         cK       # Chop this string in K pieces of equal sizes, initial piece longer if necessary
       lM         # For each string, compute the length. Here we already have our result. However if the array contain a zero, we must output a falsy value
  ?>KQ            # If K > Q...
      0           # Then display zero, otherwise display the array
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
{_2$>/,/z:,}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP2fU6eQqqwQlJqYopCZV1BaopBWlJ@rEBzi4un3vzreSMVOX0e/ykqn9j9YnWtFanJpSapCSUaqQlJOfnI2VwJI2C2/KDexBCxalFpcmlPy31jB0AAA)

This is an anonymous block that takes the input as `n m` on the stack. It would have been a good answer, but the error handling requirement completely killed it.

Errors with a divide-by-zero when it's not possible to solve.

### Explanation

```
{   e# Stack:                | 3 10
 _  e# Duplicate:            | 3 10 10
 2$ e# Copy from back:       | 3 10 10 3
 >  e# Greater than:         | 3 10 1 (true)
 /  e# Divide:               | 3 10
    e# This will cause an error on invalid input.
 ,  e# Range:                | 3 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 /  e# Split on nth element: | [[0 1 2] [3 4 5] [6 7 8] [9]]
 z  e# Transpose array:      | [[0 3 4 9] [1 4 7] [2 5 8]]
 :, e# Length of each:       | [4 3 3]
}
```

If the error-handling requirement is lifted, this can be shortened to 7 bytes, which is a decrease of over 40%:

```
{,/z:,}
```