# Is the Matrix Positive-Definite?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, matrix

### Introduction

Today we're gonna take care of the bane of first-year linear algebra students: matrix definiteness! Apparently this doesn't yet have a challenge so here we go:

### Input

- A \$n\times n\$ [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) Matrix \$A\$ in any convenient format (you may also of course only take the upper or the lower part of the matrix)
- Optionally: the size of the matrix \$n\$

### What to do?

The challenge is simple: Given a real-valued matrix \$n\times n\$ Matrix decide whether it is positive definite by outputting a truthy value if so and a falsey value if not.

You may assume your built-ins to actually work precisely and thus don't have to account for numerical issues which could lead to the wrong behaviour if the strategy / code "provably" should yield the correct result.

### Who wins?

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes (per-language) wins!

---

### What is a positive-definite Matrix anyways?

There are apparently 6 equivalent formulations of when a symmetric matrix is positive-definite. I shall reproduce the three easier ones and reference you to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations) for the more complex ones.

- If \$\forall v\in\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}: v^T Av>0\$ then \$A\$ is positive-definite. 
  This can be re-formulated as:
   If for every non-zero vector \$v\$ the (standard) dot product of \$v\$ and \$Av\$ is positive then \$A\$ is positive-definite.
- Let \$\lambda_i\quad i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\$ be the [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of \$A\$, if now \$\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}:\lambda_i>0\$ (that is all eigenvalues are positive) then \$A\$ is positive-definite. 
  If you don't know what eigenvalues are I suggest you use your favourite search engine to find out, because the explanation (and the needed computation strategies) is too long to be contained in this post.
- If the [Cholesky-Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of \$A\$ exists, i.e. there exists a lower-triangular matrix \$L\$ such that \$LL^T=A\$ then \$A\$ is positive-definite. Note that this is equivalent to early-returning "false" if at any point the computation of the root during the algorithm fails due to a negative argument.

### Examples

#### For truthy output

\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&3&0\\0&0&0&4\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}5&2&-1\\2&1&-1\\-1&-1&3\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&2\\-2&5&0\\2&0&30\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}7.15&2.45\\2.45&9.37\end{pmatrix}

#### For falsey output

(at least one eigenvalue is 0 / positive semi-definite)
\begin{pmatrix}3&-2&2\\-2&4&0\\2&0&2\end{pmatrix}

(eigenvalues have different signs / indefinite)
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}

(all eigenvalues smaller than 0 / negative definite)
\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}

(all eigenvalues smaller than 0 / negative definite)
\begin{pmatrix}-2&3&0\\3&-5&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}

(all eigenvalues smaller than 0 / negative definite)
\begin{pmatrix}-7.15&-2.45\\-2.45&-9.37\end{pmatrix}

(three positive, one negative eigenvalue / indefinite)
\begin{pmatrix}7.15&2.45&1.23&3.5\\2.45&9.37&2.71&3.14\\1.23&2.71&0&6.2\\3.5&3.14&6.2&0.56\end{pmatrix}

Comment: [This challenge was sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/16911/1).

Comment: You need to provide a better definition of what we're supposed to be looking for rather than assuming we can all read mathematical notation (or all know what an "eigenvalue" is). A worked example would be useful too.

Comment: @Shaggy I think the challenge is better without all the background to clog it up.  There are many existing explanations of what an eigenvalue is elsewhere, and this post is already really large.

Comment: @Shaggy I won't add a self-contained description / introduction of eigenvalues because this is neither the right place for that nor am I probably qualified enough to do that in a sufficient manner. I will also not add a "worked example" because there is no single "superior" strategy to this problem, because right now answers are generally using three different approaches to this challenge (either finding the eigenvalues and then checking they're positive or checking whether the cholesky decomposition exists or Sylvester's criterion).

Comment: The challenge would have been nicer hadn't you restrict the input to _symmetric_ matrices.

Comment: @SEJPM yes I noticed it. That was the point of my comment

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ oh, I misread your comment to be a complaint that symmetric matrices are not guaranteed. Also I found it to be a boring tag-on to also force people to check for symmetric-ness.

Comment: I meant just checking for the sign of eigenvalues is also boring. Different tastes I know ;)

Answer (score 10):

## C, 108 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Logern*
*-3 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

```c
f(M,n,i)double**M;{for(i=n*n;i--;)M[i/n][i%n]-=M[n][i%n]*M[i/n][n]/M[n][n];return M[n][n]>0&(!n||f(M,n-1));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVO7csIwEKytr7iQISMZKfgRKgF/4DqFowL8IDdjZMaYJuBfjyMZD014uKDQSLq9vb2TZhOxSZK2zWnENUeWlod1kbluJI95WVFcaFdLFEKyKMapVjGOtRKLKO6Pbh/WatrFtJJVVh8qDf116b3RF306dQLCZ0w27SvqpDikGcz3dYrl@/eSoK5hu0JNGRyJc@4CTBuxgoWNOLTvLFZdxiXQ3QF8DuDZBQ3/j1rEv4t2GdAYsMt4oDYz2QEH4V@tF5zVrqOiQ0xGOFjNMmzN4Go9i8xuzhacZwu9wWrhQ7WPR2qWO3y2@/8mnvhv4glqYriafY3wZj37zrOhasRpJHGMI4Fap6AxhSfNNoc9/mSlMReD6eUce4oZdDJhhrurDCOno3H6pUccLIyKQ2CcSJzeq54kDWl/k7xYbfat@NSlwO2uwARrYdh/)

Performs Gaussian elimination and checks whether all diagonal elements are positive (Sylvester's criterion). Argument `n` is the size of the matrix minus one.

Comment: Perhaps save a character with float instead of double?

Comment: [106 bytes - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVO7coMwEKzRV1ycSQZhFPOIKxn/AXUKosLh4dwMFh6Mm9j8esgJM27iB4ULhtPt3e6dNJuKdZp2XWHHrnaRZ9X@q8wdJ5aHoqptjDyJC@1oidMpjxOcaZXgi1YiipMhdIa0VrM@p5WMoyFaeq/2kz4ee3rhcy7b7hl1Wu6zHBa7JsPq7XvJUDewWaG2ORyYdZoBaIhEQWQylj3Mlai@4pzozwC@C@CZD1r3P2oQ/ybaV0BLYF9xR21O1YELwr/IF5zULqOiR6giHK1mOgxncJHPIPOruwWn3UJvtFp4V@39nprpHb/b7XcTD3w38QA1MV7N3EZ4lc/c83ysGrNaySzyI9jGKUim8CT9FrDDn7wic3GYnePEU5xQ8iv1bmvqKOzJS/apJy4YGJULATmRWXXe7GtNXKxl3W9alKv1rhMfuhK42ZaYYiOo@w8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: You can shave another character if you drop `i=0` in the for loop, make the recursive call `f(M,n-1,0)` and the initial call with 0 as the third arg.

Comment: @Jens 1. Using floats instead of doubles can quickly lead to noticable rounding errors, so I don't think the one byte saved is worth it. 2. Initializing a variable via an additional argument looks like cheating to me.

Comment: @Logern I refuse to use the "omit the return statement" trick in my C answers. But thanks for the other byte saved.

Comment: [107 bytes - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVM9b8IwEJ3jX3GloopDXPJRJhOmrpkrJc1A80FPCg4KYSnkrze1HcTSABkYLPvu3b3ns/VStknTrivM0BY20qw6fJW5ZYX8WFS1iYHDcSkswXE2o2GM8yjGacSCMNYHq09FcxVHvM6bQy1AByvnxXwSp5NmZi6lvO2eUaTlIcthuW8yrF6/VwRFA9s1CpPCkRi9PEj9OIFAZQzzfKU40RWXhI4BXBvAUQta@z@qEPcmqiuglaCuuKO2kNWeDcwd5PN6tWGUaURW@KPVVIfi9Ab5FLK4OpvXz@Y7o9X8u2pv99RU7/jZbv8be@C/sQeosfFq6jX8q3zqnRdj1YjRcmJIK4KpnILSFA6X2xL2@JNX0lwU5pdz7CRUotKqsndXy47CnEyzTzGxQcGY2OBJJxLj7FSHk5Z0v2lRrjf7jr1HgUg69iEqhttdiSk2TJL8AQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 9):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 12 bytes

```matlab
@(A)eig(A)>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZPPasMwDMbvfYrvUhofLPwnbihmY3uO0UNZnREY22i7vX4mC1PijR1qlsMnSzY/PiTl/fly@ErzeEdE80P3qNL0wnpv5mnsxu7JwsBEAyvKca9QfQrH6fzRbS6nz7RREen1nEppPPBZam9HYJ1frBZUIboSDXyJBv1eNVED07SNjs1y0Fnhl34bvWoHF1kCO8x@vama0EQdyLJd6kPMgh35oe7sjdSC9VezfTHrGrFYS76q10D/tQeNXP0LrG1bc39wnewTtyP8L1fmpmVwotD16Bq513WAJefhabEXXB94kcn2US4lNdiSi/xOLnICQ2F7y58j6fwN)

The function eig provides the eigenvalues in ascending order, so if the first eigenvalue is greater than zero, the other ones are too.

Comment: You can drop the `f=` at the beginning - anonymous functions are generally accepted as answers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Even if its a vector? Interesting

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/82619

Comment: +1. I've added a link for trying it online. Hope you don't mind. Note that it is also proving that the output values despite being arrays do count as the correct "truthy" or "falsey" values as per the link @Delfad0r posted.

Comment: Having said that, it fails for the first "falsey" test case on TIO. I'm guessing due to a precision issue - one of the Eigen values comes out as `8.9219e-17` rather than 0.

Comment: Maybe `eig(a)>eps` could help. But I don't think its a good idea.

Comment: @TomCarpenter thank you! It is in fact a precision issue: if you input the matrix as symbolic, it will yield the correct result. Altough it must be noticed that for some sym matrices the result is not a bool vector but a sym vector.

Comment: Not that your answer depends on it, but the Matlab help page for "eig" says that it doesn't guarantee the order which eigenvalues appear (certainly for non-symmetric matrices, you'll get them in non-sorted order; the algorithm currently used for symmetric matrices when detected may impose sorting).

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
ṖṖ€$ƬÆḊṂ>0
```

Uses [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBLDoIwEN1zilm4gKRDWgohbtx6CMLSjeECbllo4gE8BQeQNYn3wIvUmVJLQRNNpknfy3tvPsdD05yMGfsb1bPtNo9uOI/369i3O2mGC1FUe2PiOIoAqkoJkFS1IAQVfdUCMVETDLULQbYmqPSaoMp9ChQC2IbKaRhwW0@gBUTq2cQU67K3hgEnyTCFm0tvKlNFiizNC6fhr4BtqkurSYQ7Ak/8mZ5/SSdFOJKlvEa6sUPCvvmE@LcJAxM316GG5y1@mKbtMVgfp/1xPkDyAg)

#### How it works

```
ṖṖ€$ƬÆḊṂ>0  Main link. Argument: M (matrix)

   $Ƭ       Do the following until a fixed point is encountered.
Ṗ             Pop; remove the last row of the matrix.
 Ṗ€           Pop each; remove the last entry of each row.
     ÆḊ     Take the determinants of the resulting minors.
       Ṃ    Take the minimum.
        >0  Test if the least determinant is positive, i.e., if all determinants are.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes

```r
function(m)all(eigen(m)$va>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFBCsIwELznFQsKJrCB1Nqb@hIvMTYaaFNIU0HEt9etorShHlxyyAwzwywbervrbedNdI3ntdBVxUt3Lof/8qr3SvS1jsGZsoWtBFa5NnLGFjQQQxcvNxaOzp@44RkqVAIZvMZwhVmCiRGC4dcBBcIaZTYSEYZsSskBI@RTK5EkXY91hClQJWkKc0XWd2Wrq7a8jXPy2ZzNXA6pkgoDOdGpV9WEGt50cfmHVSZWqpInOtqh@Gml1W0TeA3Ow@eU4k5KoyO3dGZcHfxKsAfrnw)

---

Alternative using cholesky :

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>34</s>  33 bytes

```r
function(m)is.array(try(chol(m)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFBCsIwELznFQse3MBGUqs3/YmXGBsMtCmk8VDEt9dtRWmDHlz2MsPMMMvGwR0Hdws2@TZgI323MTGaHlPs0V7bmjkph8ak6G3VwUGBqH2XUIgVD6R4S9dexLMPF7RYkCYtScA0FjUVGWZGSkEfB@wJtqSKmYgxFEtKjZigXFqZZOl2rmPMgTpL01Rqtr4qO1N3VT/PKb/m7L7lsCqrMJILnZ6qZtS4y8PVH1aVWblKmen4hv1PK5/u2ogN@ADvV8o7K61J6PjFtD6FtRQPMTwB)

-1 byte thanks to @Giuseppe

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

```hs
f((x:y):z)=x>0&&f[zipWith(-)v$map(u/x*)y|u:v<-z]
f[]=1>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLasMwEDxbX@FDCVJZuXrYhIg6f9BLLz0IUXSoiajjmMYOjum/u7IiRKA5zbCzO5pdHez5@6ttl6XBeFJXomZST3u22TR6dv2HGw6YksvT0fZ4fJmeyfV3VJdXOhvUaFPzPVtc14/DOVcq11q/28GdOtsaY1AU6lyjTGsODJgBzYBH9MwYSFqsisQYyMQYlLG38h2U@7LwRoHQFUEmLypArGUBVZhfHSWL8rbg3qEoq1XwALtCbqMm70bLNCruQ4Y49P8G9KFKkyziLv6J6oEcUtEYKyDQWzCUGYSO1nX@jv4T3j5x/@O6oWjI7bwoW/4A)

Basically a port of [nwellnhof's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172682/82619). Performs gaussian elimination and checks whether the elements on the main diagonal are positive.

<s>Fails the first falsey output because of rounding errors, but it would theoretically work with infinite precision.</s> Thanks to [Curtis Bechtel's suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172677/is-the-matrix-positive-definite#comment416654_172688), now the outputs are all correct.

Comment: you can add `inputs :: [[[Rational]]]` to get correct answers

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
0<Min@Eigenvalues@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7BCgIhEAbge08RBJ1GGMe8FXjpGPQKEm4JrYdyu4jPbrNJbS7s7cf/43d6G2@ut9FfbOkOBfcnH8zRX1142fvgnmazLeeHD9F0JiUJCJhhnRDkN3DMeTUZDQRCjh0xqkmMAVTj@ImAPi2BrmvEawobpv7ZbmI0G/sdJhYvEwtKzBiBqiX/rVtW3g)

Comment: Should 4th test case be False?

Comment: @tsh Fixed, I am dumb!

Comment: Funny how Mathematica has a [builtin for this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ.html), but its name is longer than your solution.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Wouldn't a solution using NullSpace or MatrixRank be even shorter? If Null space is zero then the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: @PhilH No, I'm afraid that doesn't work by itself. For instance, the second falsey example (diagonal matrix with (1,-1,1)) has rank 3, but is not positive definite.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
Yv0>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@yzMDuv70CAqgqZKZxqZcUlZZkVKpz1aLIpOYUp3KppyUCKaBcLKpcXgqXS8j/aEMFAwUDayBhCKGAjFiuaFMFIwVdQ2sgaQimdUGUgjFQBsgwUjCyBpGmIB1GQB3GBkAJY4SECUzCCKwBaoEuig26WMR1wRJGCsYgAaB5pkgSAA)

I've noticed that for the `[3 -2 2; -2 4 0; 2 0 2]` test case, MATL calculates the `0` eigenvalue with a very small inaccuracy, computing something as low as about \$10^{-18}\$. This therefore fails the first falsy test case due to precision issues. Thanks to Luis Mendo for pointing out that a non-empty array is truthy iff all its entries differ from 0, saving 1 byte.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, I learned something new about MATL today!

Comment: My pleasure :-) Here's a [better explanation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398) by Suever. I forgot to say that for complex-valued arrays only _the real part_ is compared against zero. So `[1 2 3j]` is falsey

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
AllTrue[Eigenvalues@#,#>0&]&
```

Definition 2.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

It is possible to do it using even less bytes, @Mr. Xcoder managed to find a [5 byte MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172680/24877)!

```
YvX<0>
```

**Explanation**

```
Yv     compute eigenvalues
  X<   take the minimum
    0> check whether it is greather than zero
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BDkIhEEP3nqIXGDLMQH4MxnN8Y1y4153x@ljmo9G4acOjpdyvj1vvp@d60GPv5wyFNkUOpV92G4uzTVf4dEVhovJGcjPWaDIUHk0xWKNU5kfblXhJmY1UahuCffKF1D/hMsP2HueUfP9I/qgEtvgXH6o/OPYkBkMh2@QL)

Comment: [Fails](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P7IswsbA7v//aGMFXSMFI2sQaaJgYK1gpGCgYBQLAA) on the first falsy test case. See [my deleted answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172680/59487).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh, you even submitted an answer before me. I think you should undelete your answer as it just depends on rounding issues. (I think you can expect answers to use limited precision arithmetic - I think only the CAS languages here use exact computations.)

Comment: Following your advice, I've [undeleted it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172680/59487).

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
using LinearAlgebra
isposdef
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v7Q4My9dwSczLzWxyDEnPTWpKJErs7ggvzglNe3/fwA)

---

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 8 bytes

```julia
isposdef
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/s7ggvzglNe3/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra%2fIsDefinite), 33 bytes

(i.e. my 2 cents)

```
with(LinearAlgebra):
IsDefinite(A)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG; I am unfamiliar with Maple, though is the newline necessary?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Hello and thanks. No it's not. I didn't count it btw.

Comment: To me your current byte count seems to reflect the newline character.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Duh, my bad

Comment: Well ... now your code and your byte count disagree.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>99 95</s>  88 bytes

Same method as [nwellnhof's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172682/58563). Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```javascript
f=(m,n=0,R=m[n])=>R?f(m,n+1)&R[m.map((r,y)=>y<n&&R.map((v,x)=>r[x]-=v*r[n]/R[n])),n]>0:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLLboMwELzzFZx4tLZrGxzUB@mtH4B6QxxQGvoQmAhSFL6ernFDQaQkQT54xzvj8SxfaZPWm@pzt8eyfNt2XRY6BZIhRVFYxDJxw3X0nCnolrlWFBekSHeOU6EWTtonaVmRRhp0AKSKDwkOm5sKqHeR4rtIJmv6wLpNKesy35K8fHfs1@p7/9Ha7qMxhjMnNkz4YoZMCitBuoQ9m5YKSQxQXxaYkvgMgeXNEFj@krbolTA7snjv7q/GfQXKZwxiIPKBBIUYWdFePbqkERCmvBBfDCzYI/OeeMEvb0K0X9K8/j9074Qlf2aJXxD7KE985eDwRRJ4WYNPx6oeJq7V0OHicbpYx4tH@Z6ZCzyWcLjeI4LOZ6R6AvWjEOYfT3W/ximh4HNF@MBVQrpf46pHrLSX7gc)